# What's the font used in code blocks?

Tags: support, fonts

I quite like the look of the font used in the code blocks that appear on Stack Overflow.

What, dear listener, is the font face used for such?

Answer (score 81):

It's the first font in the following list that is installed on your system:

- Consolas
- Monaco
- Lucida Console
- Liberation Mono
- DejaVu Sans Mono
- Bitstream Vera Sans Mono
- Courier New

For more information, look at the CSS file in Firebug.

Comment: +1 It's good to make the point that it depends on what fonts are installed in the client.

Comment: and the browser defined ones...

Answer (score 23):

```
code {
  background-color:#EEEEEE;
  font-family:Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New;
}
```

Comment: No `monospace`? I am disappoint.

Comment: Edited and fixed ;)

Comment: @Ignacio: There's a reason `monospace` isn't used, and that reason is WebKit, which renders it differently than all other browsers.

Comment: I love it.  Snagging this for my site.css.

Answer (score 8):

StackExchange recently changed their code font. The font stack is now different per operating system.

```js
ui-monospace, // San Francisco Mono on macOS and iOS
"Cascadia Mono", "Segoe UI Mono", // Newer Windows monospace fonts that 
                                  // are optionally installed. Most likely 
                                  // to be rendered in Consolas
"Liberation Mono", // Recently updated
Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, // A few sensible system font choices
monospace // The final fallback for rendering in monospace.
```

See this [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364048/555764) for more details.

Comment: Aaand this answer is outdated twice already...

Comment: Updated accordingly, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 7):

See Super User:

- [Utility to determine the font used on a site?](https://superuser.com/questions/43280/utility-to-determine-the-font-used-on-a-site/)
- [How to capture fonts from the websites?](https://superuser.com/questions/41964/how-to-capture-fonts-from-the-websites)

Comment: Careful, Arjan, you are currently implying that there would be useful information on SU? That would be shocking!

Comment: @Gnoupi, you know how all the questions that are too difficult for SO are delegated to SU. ;-)