# We are switching to system fonts on May 10, 2021

Tags: discussion, design, stack-exchange, fonts

**Update 3** - The changes from round 2 are live, but with one notable exception: On Linux, we spec’d “Liberation Sans” and “Liberation Mono”. Did some digging on [that PR](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/642) and installed a few Linux VMs and found Liberation to be the best way to normalize across Linux distros. It also solves an issue where Ubuntu Mono—regardless of how you feel about the typeface—is smaller than its sans-serif counterpart.

*Also noteworthy*, we aren’t touching webkit antialiasing right now. I was reacting to a change in macOS `11.3` that removes the ability to set antialiasing at the OS-level. I hope it’s a bug, and is patched up in `11.4`.

Plenty of little bugs to squash yet, and I’m chipping away at them. If something feels off on Windows, do revisit your ClearType settings. I’ve seen some folks realize with this switch that they were running some non-stock antialiasing.

---

**Update 2** - Alright folks, got some follow-up for you. You can see I’m considering some changes over at the [Stacks repo](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/642). Sidenote: *did you know our front-end library is open source and y’all can see what we’re up to?*

1. macOS and iOS continue to get San Francisco
2. Windows continues to get Segoe, but we drop `system-ui` since it isn’t quite ready for primetime.
3. Linux gets “Arial” which is never Arial, but often Liberation Sans, or Noto, but maintains the status quo.
4. Android gets Roboto, but we don’t specify it since it was clobbering Debian
5. If all else fails, `sans-serif`.

As for general font sizes, I think our fonts have always been too small. The base font size is `13px` and we even show some bits of UI at `11px`. I’ve got long term goals of [bumping those up a point or two](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/643). I hear y’all with aging eyes. Mine are also aging—always have been, always will be

I’ve read every comment and answer here and I think this strikes a balance between how we want to move forward and issues people have had in good faith. I’ll get to chipping away at the small issues once we iron out the bigger ones.

If this follow-up works, I’ll make sure to update the screenshots in this original post in a third update.

---

**Update 1** - These changes are now live!

TL;DR We’re shipping system fonts as our default font stack. We plan to do this on May 10th, 2021.

### What?

We’re planning on specifying system fonts on Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange Network. On macOS and iOS, you’ll see things set in San Francisco. On Windows, you’ll see Segoe. On Android you’ll get Roboto. Ubuntu will show, well, Ubuntu. We’ll also use their monospace equivalents when writing in code or rendering keyboard keys.

| OS | Sans | Mono |
| --- | --- | --- |
| macOS | San Francisco | San Francisco Mono |
| iOS | San Francisco | San Francisco Mono |
| Windows | Segoe UI | Consolas, or Cascadia Mono, Segoe UI Mono if you've installed those manually |
| Ubuntu | Ubuntu | Ubuntu Mono |
| Android | Roboto | Roboto Mono |
| Chrome OS | Roboto | Roboto Mono |
| Fallback | `sans-serif` | Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, `monospace` |

We’re leaving serif fonts alone so those will stay as Georgia, Cambria, Times New Roman, Times, and then `serif` as a fallback. We really don't do much with serifs anyway, and we don’t want to mess with the themes that rely on them.

Here’s the exact font stack we’ve specified that’ll go live on the 10th.

```
@ff-sans:
    system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, // San Francisco on macOS and iOS
    "Segoe UI", // Windows
    "Ubuntu", // Ubuntu
    "Roboto", "Noto Sans", "Droid Sans", // Chrome OS and Android with fallbacks
    sans-serif; // The final fallback for rendering in sans-serif.
@ff-serif: Georgia, Cambria, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
@ff-mono:
    ui-monospace, // San Francisco Mono on macOS and iOS
    "Cascadia Mono", "Segoe UI Mono", // Newer Windows monospace fonts that are optionally installed. Most likely to be rendered in Consolas
    "Ubuntu Mono", // Ubuntu
    "Roboto Mono", // Chrome OS and Android
    Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, // A few sensible system font choices
    monospace; // The final fallback for rendering in monospace.
```

#### Why?

Mark Otto put it really well on his personal blog, documenting [GitHub’s rationale](https://markdotto.com/2018/02/07/github-system-fonts/) for switching. Like GitHub, our original font stack used Arial across macOS, iOS, and Windows. Arial was first created in 1982, and has served the web well for *decades*. But technology moves on. Modern system typefaces look better on both new high DPI screens, and old screens alike. Apple’s San Francisco and Microsoft’s Segoe both look great on retina displays, have more expressive weights, and improve readability across all contexts. With more weights, we can have better hierarchy. We can also get more expressive. For example, in dark mode, we could [drop our font weights a bit for better readability](https://css-tricks.com/dark-mode-and-variable-fonts/).

#### But what about consistency?

We originally chose Arial because it was available on the widest set of devices, allowing us to have a consistent experience wherever you were. However, Arial doesn’t ship with Linux distros or Android devices. We’re currently only achieving consistency between macOS, iOS, and Windows, leaving 2 platforms to choose their system font. We’d rather have the consistency be shifted to the device itself—when viewing Stack Overflow on iOS, it’ll feel that much more native in San Francisco. Same with Android, which is already being displayed in Roboto.

We should also note that prior to these changes, our monospace font stack varied wildly. Now you'll have better consistency between sans and monospace, since we'll do our best to choose the right pairings.

#### Will my Stack Exchange site lose its custom font?

Nope! This change will not affect sites that have their own typefaces. Sites like Christianity and English will still be displayed in their custom fonts.

#### Future possibilities

If consistency were the absolute goal, we’d ship our own custom font. I would love to be able to truly express our brand through a typeface, but that means users would have to download custom fonts and wait for them to display. We’d also have to cover international character sets. Displaying custom fonts is getting more realistic every day at our scale, so we may revisit that choice at some point, and come back to a more consistent experience. System fonts let us modernize in the meantime without too many drawbacks.

Also, since a lot of our site is built using our [design system](https://www.stackoverflow.design/), we can store these font stacks as CSS variables. We could allow users to more easily specify dyslexia-friendly typefaces, or load their own entirely.

#### Some screenshots

**Safari on macOS**
[image: Safari on macOS]

**Firefox on Windows**
[image: Firefox on Windows]

**Firefox on Ubuntu**
[image: Firefox on Ubuntu]

#### So what now?

When this change drops, we could use your help in discovering any bugs—things like unexpected alignment, or any questionable bits where we clearly got the wrong typeface.

Comment: Is there a schedule for the roll out to the rest of the network?

Comment: Hopefully this will prevent issues like ['pom’ getting mistaken for ‘porn’](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/58767/9161) in the future.

Comment: @DavidPostill This change is global, affecting the whole network. If your network has the default font, that'll change on the 10th.

Comment: Would still be nice if all the fonts made the difference between l and I (bonus points for not noticing which is which) substantially more noticeable, at least along the lines of what the Ubuntu font does.

Comment: @Zoethe1337Princess I emphatically agree, but alas, here we are. This is the quickest, least bytes-over-the-wire way we can get to more modern fonts.

Comment: A welcome change as long as it doesn't [break Tony the Pony](https://jlericson.com/2018/12/17/tony_the_pony.html).;-)

Comment: @JonEricson Had a look on macOS and it looks good!

Comment: How is the "system font" determined when I visit the site? Is browser detection used to choose the CSS to supply? What assurance is there that the selected font is really available on my system? Has Linux been replaced with Ubuntu, or is the rest of Linux just relegated to "fallback" mode? Is this change, needed or not, going to be accompanied by the implementation of dark mode for the rest of the sites?

Comment: @Chindraba ... Really confused why dark mode has anything to do with font choices.

Comment: Not related directly, just if they're gonna tweak CSS across the board, adding the CSS for dark mode at the same time might be less of a burden. Or not. Just asking?

Comment: Many of our sites have custom designs that do not work in dark mode, @Chindraba Making the network dark would require significant design work to actually have it look good across the platform. The only "easy" set of sites would be sites with the default/beta theme.

Comment: The waiting continues. How about the bulk of the comment, before mention of dark mode?

Comment: I'll leave that to Aaron, but it might make a better answer than a comment, @Chindraba :)

Comment: I decided to see what this would look like BUT San Francisco does not seem to be available on my macOS BigSur

Comment: @Milliways - San Fransisco is not a user font, it's a system font. As such it doesn't appear in Font Book etc. Initially, Apple kept a tight license on it, meaning it could only be used for Apple product mockups etc, but they seem to have relaxed that in recent times. You can download it if you need it as a user font, but you don't need to for it to display correctly - https://developer.apple.com/fonts/

Comment: What about non-ubuntu linux?

Comment: Not in favour of MS clear type fonts it would be nice if there was an easy way to swap back to Arial or any other preferred font. Ideally any relevant HTML tag would get another class attribute so that it would be easy to re-style e. g. according to [this super user answer](https://superuser.com/a/532623).

Comment: @Aconcagua Which linux are you running? We could add in the system font for that if needed.

Comment: @AaronShekey I am on Linux too (Arch, FWIW). Why not just default to sans-serif on all Linux? The user can set it to whatever they want in their browser settings. On Ubuntu, it will default to Ubuntu font anyway.

Comment: @prash Defaulting to `sans-serif` does not render the system font. `sans-serif` on Ubuntu renders as `DejaVu Sans`. Specifying `Ubuntu` ensures that Ubuntu renders in its system font. We can include more fonts from various linux distros if needed, but I want to make the point absolutely clear: `sans-serif` does _not_ equal your system font.

Comment: @AaronShekey I see. I was just about to propose defaulting to `DejaVu Sans` :-) As a user (and mod) of linguistics.SE, we often come across some weird characters. Ubuntu font fails to render some of them, but  `DejaVu Sans` handles them just fine.  Here is an example: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/34810/what-does-the-diacritic-in-e%CC%AF-%C9%94%CA%8F%CC%AF-mean

Comment: I would prefer Source Sans/Serif/Code Pro series of fonts.

Comment: @prash That post looks ok in "Ubuntu"  Here's a [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cvm0g7fwtxn2s1x/Screen%20Shot%202021-05-06%20at%201.00.35%20PM.png?dl=0).

Comment: @ErkinAlpGüney So would our marketing designers. You'll notice our [marketing pages](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) are set in Source Sans. We can justify the font downloads there since the audience is _so_ much smaller. Fun fact, when I worked at Adobe we gave those typeface designers lots of feedback that we'd like to discern between `I` and `l` so that's why their lowercase `l`s have curves. I also use Source Sans in a [side project](https://justhum.com).

Comment: This is my screenshot of this post, taken with all fonts replaced by Adobe Source Sans/Serif/Code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WRFu.png

Comment: @AaronShekey Maybe there is something misconfigured on my system then. This is how it looks for me, Ubuntu on top, Dejavu Sans bottom. https://i.imgur.com/flOAdCy.jpg. Thanks for your clarifications! I'll go fix my setup.

Comment: @prash Shoot! I'm on a pristine VirtualBox image from osboxes.org so I don't think anything's different on my end. Good luck!

Comment: _I would prefer Source Sans/Serif/Code Pro series of fonts._ And I’m sure other people would have their own font preferences too, @ErkinAlpGüney

Comment: Not relevant to my answer and raised in a prior comment. Raising it here, as a single point to not get lost in a multi-point comment. What method is being used to control what font will be used? Non-exclusive options include; `User-Agent` parsing, JS-based feature testing, well-crafted font stack, use of `system-ui`, or other `ui-*` font-family generic names, in the font stack, and CSS media queries. There may be other methods I've not considered. Unless it's a secret for some reason, it'd be nice to know how the selection is made so we, as users of the network, can do some of our own testing.

Comment: Somehow I missed the update to show the proposed font stack. It has some errors. `system-ui` will select a font based on the browser's decision on almost every browser and OS. Notable exceptions are IE, Firefox, Opera Mini, and Firefox on Android. Worse yet, `ui-monospace` will only work on Safari and Safari on iOS, all other broswers on MacOS and iOS will _not_ get the San Francisco Mono, instead falling through to who knows what. In both cases, as I do not have any of the named fonts installed, my system falls through to the ultimate fallback, which is perfect for me.

Comment: I would be so happy to see code blocks in Inconsolata-g, my favourite programming and default system monospace font.

Comment: *"We really don't do much with serifs anyway"* - There are entire sites like [physics.SE] with a serif font as their main font. Are we to take from that that we are not really being considered at all by SE's designers currently?

Comment: @AaronShekey Running on Devuan with LXDE on private machine (Win10 for work – forcefully...).

Comment: @ACuriousMind I would like to address those communities separately since a relative few use serif fonts.

Comment: There are so many linux distributions that might need to be considered – and BSD currently is not considered at all in the list. With any new system one might have to consider maintenance will require more effort. Having doubts about this being a very good idea. One font for all systems might mean less hassle, though this does not solve the problem of innumerous screen resolutions existing.

Comment: It seems arbitrary to simply pick Ubuntu out of thin air to be representative for Linux. What about openSUSE, Archlinux, Debian, etc... We will see how it goes, but this looks like another solution in search of a problem. I'd rather see Stack lead than just follow what github does...

Comment: I use Linux with a Windows user agent string, so who knows what's going to happen.

Comment: @Boann Font selection has nothing to do with user agent strings. It will choose the first font that’s available on your machine. 

Comment: @AaronShekey I have all the Windows fonts installed.

Comment: @Boann My bet’s on Segoe UI, since it’s listed first in our stack. Interesting!

Comment: Did you purposely not put Chrome screenshots because you know everyone is using it?

Comment: @abelmelquiadescallejo Yes! Me and the boys were thinking of fun conspiracies and this is what we landed on.  Nah, I asked a volunteer to get me a screenshot on Windows and their Chrome was full of extensions and a bit of personal info, so they switched to Firefox. I did the same on Linux. Personally, I use Safari and Brave on macOS. And then I got busy and didn’t include iOS and Android just to mess with you.

Comment: I once had an issue on SE where "click" read like "dick" everywhere https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5180/kerning-issues-click-reads-like-dick-letter-spacing

Comment: @Matsemann bad [keming](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/keming) has always been a problem.

Comment: @MarkRansom I’ll update the post when it’s ready. Probably around 11 or noon central if there aren’t any fires to put out. It’s my Sunday night at the moment and that means watching episodes of The Larry Sanders show. 

Comment: I use Ubuntu Linux and see Segoe UI because I installed it manually. But Segoe UI is definitely not a "system" font (my system font is still Ubuntu, it's configured in DE settings and my browser settings). I'm not sure that calling it "system fonts" is correct.

Comment: I see screenshots of the UI, but none showing the effect on the editor. On Windows the editor font is now bold, and I think it didn't used to be monospace, but it appears to be now. Can the change to the editor be undone?

Comment: @JasonAller The editor has always been monospace, unless you're using the beta of the rich text editor. Makes it easy to create tables prior to tables being a thing.

Comment: @FreeMan Since my previous comment on this was deleted, can someone tell me what the original font on linux was so I can go back to it?

Comment: @SurpriseDog Try [the userscript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364268/custom-fonts-user-script-revert-or-improve-the-font-updates).

Comment: Just chiming in to offset all the complaints, and to say that the change is a vast improvement on macOS with Chrome. There are possibly very legitimate issues, both with the idea behind then change and with the execution, but at least on some platforms it works incredibly well.

Comment: Could we have this as an option in our preferences?  That way it'd look OK across most browsers, instead of excluding most in favor of, seemingly, macOS.

Comment: @ACuriousMind "There are entire sites like Physics with a serif font as their main font." - true, and it is a brain-dead typographic decision to have non-lining numerals by default on a science site. But experience says we shouldn't expect any better from SE, of course.

Comment: @SurpriseDog You can use `body *:not(textarea) { font-family: arial !important; }` in a custom user style to return to the old fonts.

Comment: @TylerH Thanks, this works well for post body text, any idea how to mimic the previous font style for `code` blocks on Windows?

Comment: I am not going to refresh my default filter page as long as possible :{.

Comment: Please make this a toggle in the settings. The fonts look truly horrific

Comment: Very helpful: [Custom Fonts User Script: Revert the Font Updates](https://stackapps.com/q/8932/66257)

Comment: @leonheess https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364279/add-the-font-changes-as-options-in-our-preferences

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Update the selector to this so that it doesn't change code fonts: `body:not(#chat-body) *:not(textarea):not(code)`

Comment: Descenders are clipped.  q and g now look the same in an edit box in Chrome Windows.  (For example, when typing in the search box, or when editing a post to change the title.)

Comment: This is a bad change. At least on AskUbuntu - site that I visit (or visited) most often the Ubuntu font is much less readable than plain sans-serif, be it Arial, Liberation or whatever. I get tired just from browsing the site. It may look as a nice nice idea for someone who is only **looking** at Stack sites, but definitely not for someone who actually **reads** them. The whole effect of this will be that it will simply discourage me from visiting the site too often, just to save my eyes. :(

Comment: what an awful font for `code 4 =>`. look at four. and no ligatures.

Comment: On [Physics.se], the system font is not applied everywhere – it appears on usernames, "edit"/"follow" etc., tags, also in the inbox, but not in the actual title or question/answers. See https://imgur.com/a/9cjb0pY

Comment: Cascadia mono is definitely not an improvement ! I reverted to Consolas. Segoe, yes it is better.

Comment: Oh my eyes... this font seems piexlized, too much curves, I am on Windows Chrome.... Don't like it...

Comment: Grainy not sharp (Firefox/Windows). _Very_ taxing on these old eyes. But since the Medicare cohort is not the target audience......

Comment: @Jonas Serif fonts didn't change. The parts of the page that are sans-serif did.

Comment: I like the Ubuntu font, but it isn't something I'd like to see on SE or system-wide. It isn't a default font on KUbuntu (and vanilla Ubuntu too IIRC)!

Comment: I kind of understand the rationale behind this, but it's just not great.  Next time we should do a 12-site test like with the 3-vote close options, or an alpha test.

Comment: The new fonts don't line up with other UI elements properly. I wish I could tell you more, but I don't know what fonts they are.

Comment: Ewww (Windows 10). Can we have the old ones back please?

Comment: Another Windows 10 + Chrome user here who hates this change. I think it looks even worse on StackOverflow **dark** mode. Code fonts look blown out (font-weight) and fuzzy at the edges. Smaller fonts like in comments are spindly, especially when _italicised_.

Comment: I love SO Community, it makes a lightning-fast solution fixing any such Update. Thanks everyone who helped me to revert this. Segoe UI in current configuration is eye-bleeding font.

Comment: As a Windows 10 user with an old, 23" 1080p display, I am definitely against this change. The sans-serif font is just slightly too thin for me to read comfortably, and at the same time the monospace font looks... almost blurry. My eyes are watering after reading the top couple answers here.

Comment: It's curious that the post mentions GitHub, because in github.com I can read all the text without having a headache - and more important: no need to zoom it, or use userscripts or whatever. I'd also like to add that I never had to zoom any page to properly read it, until yesterday (thanks, SE!)

Comment: Indeed, GitHub uses `-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif,Apple Color Emoji,Segoe UI Emoji`, not the Ubuntu font which is completely inappropriate for the purpose of displaying large amounts of text to read.

Comment: It's possible to drop Ubuntu, but I wanted to have the clean logic of trying to show the system font where appropriate. When I worked at GitHub, I remember a bit of conversation about where we should draw the line there. "System fonts but only for macOS and Windows" felt weird, but that's what was ultimately shipped.

Comment: On non-Ubuntu linux, vanilla fontconfig will set `system-ui` to Cantarell, so putting `system-ui` at the top of the font stack will end up pairing Cantarell with Ubuntu Mono, which causes the mismatch [described in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364275/939149).

Comment: Also considering dropping `system-ui` because of non-English Windows. https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/642

Comment: As a nearly 50 year old viewing the site on Windows 10, this change is terrible for my aging eyes.

Comment: Using Chrome in Ubuntu, some diacritics are not properly displayed. This ruins the proper visualization of - IMO - [one of the most classic and famous answers in SE's history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454). This is unacceptable (I know it's probably a corner case, yet, it's a notorious answer and should deserve a better treatment) :-)

Comment: Switching on ClearType helps with some of the problems, for all you Windows users, like making "I E" look like I E and not an E with a thick back, but it's not a magic solution.  Things are still kinda swirly.

Comment: While the site remains perfectly useable on Android, and iPad, it's an unmitigated visual disaster on Ubuntu 20.04. Please, this cannot - or, rather, *should not* - be allowed to persist, it's quite literally both painful and a constant deterrent to contributing to the site in any way (I don't regard composing answers on a mobile device to be acceptable means of contribution in any meaningful way).

Comment: So starting now, should we start creating repositories on StackOverflow? Or post our questions and answers on GitHub?

Comment: You've made a few very subjective statements as if they are objectively true - claiming something "looks better" is subjective, not objective, as is "improve readability across all contexts" readability of a specific font compared to another is very subjective to the person doing the reading.

Comment: My eyes hurt on windows, is this normal? When can I expect to have gotten used to it?

Comment: My main complaint: bold is too bold.

Comment: *I wanted to have the clean logic of trying to show the system font where appropriate*: you keep saying “system font”, but that’s not what these fonts are. They are actually system **user interface** fonts. So, they are appropriate *nowhere* for body text. They are designed for things like window titles or menu items, which are short phrases. As the font self-description says, “The new Ubuntu Font Family was started to enable the personality of Ubuntu to be seen and felt in every **menu, button and dialog**”. It is sheer luck that the Windows UI font is passable as a general-purpose font.

Comment: I'm a Windows user, and I've never liked Segoe UI. Looks decent on an Xbox, but not on the web. Give us the choice of toggling system fonts. Arial might be old, but it is *readable*.

Comment: Also I'm glad that you are considering dropping Ubuntu fonts too, because non-Ubuntu Linux can still have Ubuntu fonts installed, and using Ubuntu fonts on those systems wouldn't be consistent with the system fonts. For example, on Arch, the very popular ttf-google-fonts-git package provides Ubuntu fonts. On Ubuntu variants with alternative DEs like X(L/K)ubuntu, the fonts-ubuntu package comes installed as well. Since users may have chosen these variants precisely because they didn't like the look of vanilla Ubuntu, giving Ubuntu fonts priority wouldn't be appropriate for them.

Comment: @psdpainter It may finally be time to start playing around with [user stylesheets](https://superuser.com/a/319322/114388) again.

Comment: This font change introduces difficulty for me to read the text on stack websites, specifically, the monospace font used on windows for syntax highlighting looks fat and is hard to read, the segue ui font as others have commented, looks like a comic sans-inspired design.  Why isn't this an option for users to decide to use?

Comment: @ruffin I dread having to do this, but you're right.

Comment: Arial is actually more readable for me on Windows. Segoe UI looks too thin and is uncomfortable for reading texts.

Comment: Just wanted to chime in and say [tuning ClearType on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1337898/how-to-reset-the-font-in-windows-10/1338159#1338159) *measurably* improved the look and readability of fonts on SE for me on my machine. If you haven't tried it yet and don't have it disabled intentionally, you should give it a try.

Comment: Did the font size change for comments? It seems pretty small when I read on a mobile device. I have to really strain my eyes (or just pinch to zoom).  I am getting old but I hope that's not the only reason 

Comment: @CaveJohnson Ah, you're right, it did. We ought to be keeping those put at their original size. Hey, I'm getting old too!

Comment: The new fonts used for comments (**smaller, thinner**) on Android makes them more difficult to read. This is not a improvement.

Comment: Please put `Consolas` back before `Cascadia` for Windows users ([reason here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364390/): Cascadia is much bolder than any other font, and impossible to uninstall)

Comment: @zcoop98 Sorry, are you SERIOUSLY recommending I change my WINDOWS settings so a single website doesn't have an unreadable font, while all other websites do NOT have this issue? That's like using a bazooka to kill a fly...

Comment: @Nzall Yes, I am; it's a simple setup step that might help improve some people's experience across the board, on way more than just Stack (it applies to fonts across the board). That's not overkill, and doesn't equate to a bazooka lol.

Comment: People are still using fonts that web sites push on them?  Learn CSS and use your own fonts (and font sizes), people!

Comment: Not an expert in any form... But I noticed the site is now significantly harder to read. The fonts are smaller than my comfort threshold, So much that I have changed default scaling on SE pages to 125% (which unfortunately blurs many font elements)

Comment: Well, the main argument for the change seems to be "Like github!1". The referenced blog post doesn't have any meaningful reasoning either apart from "the fonts are good, but these are decades old...". I don't give a flying shit whether SO looks like GitHub or not. I just want the text to be comfortable to read. Which is not anymore. It's extremely thin and painful to look at on macOS.

Comment: Please don't use Cascadia Mono, it looks too bold, why not just Consolas or DejaVu Sans Mono?

Comment:  macOS Big Sur user here. The experience under Safari, Firefox, MS Edge and Chrome/Brave is _superb_. I hadn't been following this proposed change, so it came as a huge surprise when suddenly all these SO sites became _so_ much more readable. At least for me, of course; YMMV (Note: I also liked GitHub's change, for the same reason).

The only thing that I personally prefer is the amazingly cool [FiraCode](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) font for mono, since in most cases, mono is used on SO for displaying _code_, so, well, FiraCode  (actually I use the Nerd edition with 5000+ glyphs)

Comment: ... interestingly, Wikipedia seems to be using now `sans-serif`, which basically means 'pick your own font' (or else, the OS & browser will pick one for you instead)

Comment: The `preformated` code blocks with syntax highlighting often look good, but the ones that aren't seem harder to read. This is more problematic with bash/shell blocks that don't do much syntax highlighting to begin with and tend to be pretty crammed into one-liners. (Feedback on Windows)

Comment: Arial (though actually Cantarell in my case) is not a good choice for anyone at any time. Have we been transported back to the 1990s?

Comment: I use Vivaldi (on both Pi & macOS) and didn't notice any difference. I and l appear similar, but I have manually installed San Francisco which DOES distinguish between the 2.

Comment: Just as a data point, I love the look of most sites now, but the serif fonts on physics.SE and math.SE look undefinably sort of weird to me. I can't put my finger on why exactly.

Comment: Secondly, as a fellow person with poor eyesight, I think it's great that you're increasing the font sizes, but I can't wait for the rest of the text elements to catch up - I generally use the browser's zoom to put the text at a readable size, but currently if I can read the comments comfortably then the main text is too big. You did mention you're working on that, though.

Comment: Why do you describe https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/643 as a "long-term goal" -- how long until it will be merged to production?

Comment: I noticed the font change and *then* noticed the meta post about font changes. It's really not nice. I've just had to zoom in quite a bit to increase readability. As others have said, I don't really see why striving to look different - yet native, apparently - in different ecosystems is desirable. Coke don't change their logo for different audiences.

Comment: Chipping in and I know it'll be completely ignored (because who am I) but come on, this is awful. 
System UI font (Mac, Chrome + Safari) is SO SLOW to read.
Sleek rounded characters look good etc but readability suffers when text is "too consistent". 
There are countless studies out there looking at text legibility. Please check them out via Google Scholar.
This is a poor decision, poorly researched and poorly executed.

Comment: With how thin the font has been made it makes the text very unpleasant to read (MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)). It would be good if it was changed to something else (bolder), or added as a setting which each user could adjust as they need.  Personally I think an informative site should opt for better readability rather than fancy designs/fonts.

Comment: Update 3 on Windows 10 has a bad effect on code. The font looks way too narrow. Checked the ClearType settings. I think it doesn't pick "Segoe UI Mono". It would pick it up with just "Segoe UI". Is Windows 10 supposed to have "Segoe UI Mono"?

Comment: mine falls back to consolas, win 10 chrome. code blocks look fine here

Comment: @trincot What is it rendering in? If you haven't installed Windows Terminal (Cascadia Mono), or Segoe UI Mono, it should show up as Consolas, which is what we were rendering things in before any of these changes.

Comment: (Quick note - I've cleaned up a lot of the non specific critical comments like "I hate it" and "it makes my head hurt/eyes bleed/cat pregnant". If there's specific critiques - its probably a good idea to check if its made before and post an answer with full details and *screenshots*. )

Comment: @AaronShekey, it displays as "Liberation Mono" on my Win10. The next matching font would have been Consolas, which looks much better in my opinion (possibly because that's what I was used to see before). Reading [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberation_fonts) I think I got "Liberation Mono" because of LibreOffice installation.

Comment: @trincot I also suddenly get "Liberation Mono" here on my Win7 computer after Update #3. Didn't know that this font exists on my system. Likely you are right as I also have LibreOffice installed. Consolas definitely looks better on Windows.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that tuning clearType on Windows doesn't help much since the font itself has too little weight. Guess its time to fiddle around with custom userStyles to revert this.

Comment: Thank you for the "Update 3" updates, I have my old font back. Wholeheartedly agree with you that the whole thing needs to go up a point or two (I'd suggest two). *"Here’s the exact font stack we’ve specified that’ll go live on the 10th."* I think the block following that is out of date now.

Comment: Liberation Sans is even worse than Ubuntu...

Comment: I really tried to get used to see code blocks with Liberation Mono, but I have to give up. It just doesn't look right. Installed a user script to get Consolas back.

Comment: BTW, Arial is a built-in font on Windows, so why change it? Windows is heavily optimized for Arial. Segoe UI looks much worse.

Comment: "_If something feels off on Windows, do revisit your ClearType settings_" - I've turned ClearType on and off and tried to select different boxes for readability but it does nothing to change the way the new code blocks looks on Windows. The font is still much larger than before and you now have to scroll horizontally to see all the code in posts that fitted in the code blocks just fine before. Do I need to _uninstall_ fonts to get the old font and font size back?

Comment: To revert this senseless change, see the excellent https://stackapps.com/questions/8932/custom-fonts-user-script-revert-or-improve-the-font-updates

Comment: On Windows when using bold italic code formatted text it is displayed using cursive writing: _**`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy`**_; _**`ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY`**_. This is pretty difficult to read; can be seen [here](https://superuser.com/a/1011413) for "id_rsa.pub".

Comment: @Marcono1234 - I have an answer pointing this out

Comment: I noticed changes about 15 minutes or so ago, what exactly did change (I'm a MacOs user)

Comment: **Chrome extension** to revert fonts (and other changes): https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/revert-stackexchange-form/fliedkodjpgomjmjbkaehhlllnhmcjnh

Answer (score 198):

[support](/questions/tagged/support)

Now that this has gone live... Serious question:

How do I go back?

The new font chosen (Using Firefox in Windows 10) feels substantially harder to read and has some gnarly issues with anti-aliasing, to the point that italic text is nearly painful to read, especially in comments.

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364166/348196).

Comment: This is our plan going forward. I would recommend sitting with these changes for more than 5 minutes, but I hear ya. If you're comfortable writing your own CSS, you can override the `--ff-sans` variable to have our old font stack which is `Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif`.

Comment: @AaronShekey Any chance to get a user script to change the font?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz https://github.com/openstyles/stylus

Comment: @AaronShekey Having a play around with multiple settings, I think my biggest issue is, it feels like this change hasn't taken into account high DPI devices, it looks... okay I guess?, while running at 200% scaling in 4K, but any less than that is extremely uncomfortable, and I have no intention of using my screen at 200% scaling, ta for CSS heads up

Comment: @Nick Our intent with the system font switch is that they look better on high DPI _and_ 1x screens. I use both throughout my day.

Comment: I can live with most of the changes, but reading comments specifically (whatever the system-ui default is for Windows at 13px) is straining my eyes, so I'll be reverting to the old font stack with a userscript as well until this is addressed.

Comment: From the wayback machine: `body{--ff-sans:Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;--ff-serif:Georgia,Times New Roman,Times,serif;--ff-mono:Consolas,Menlo,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New,monospace,sans-serif;}`

Comment: Here's a UserScript I just threw together, adjust the `@match` to taste: https://gist.github.com/patrickroberts/3b3a89cb38c94c8eb591443e329cc768 click the "Raw" button to automatically prompt installation if you already have Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey.

Comment: As a (slightly) older person, I have to say Segoe is much harder to read than Arial, which has always been incredibly clear for me. I'm now going to have to go and figure out a way to reset my fonts back to ones I can read without getting a headache :-(

Comment: Here's a userstyle that fixes both sans and monospace (and hardcoded code block fonts) https://gist.github.com/SuperStormer/60a5e5c7e9549e9ed865a579df6f11be

Comment: [Custom Fonts User Script: Revert the Font Updates](https://stackapps.com/q/8932/66257)

Comment: The new Windows fonts are too small for me.  I'd like to go back too.  Also the focus should have been on readability , not UI.

Comment: A lot of these complaints just seem to be a problem with Firefox? I use Edge, and loaded up Firefox to compare and the text rendering across the board in FF just looks worse (1080p, 100% scaling). Also perhaps because Segoe UI is slightly thinner than Arial?

Comment: Yeah, the Windows monospace font looks bold and blurry.

Comment: On my machine, Firefox is inconsistently rendering the text using grayscale anti-aliasing versus subpixel anti-aliasing depending on the SE site you're on. For example, it's grayscale on Meta SO, but subpixel on SO and MSE. It's truly bewildering considering the CSS is the same. Subpixel is always used on Edge and Chrome. WPF ClearType [lets you configure this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.textrenderingmode); there isn't a standardized equivalent in CSS yet.

Comment: @AaronShekey they look better _to you_ on high DPI and 1x screens. How good things look, and comparative judgements are subjective. There are a lot of issues that have been overlooked, people with bad eyesight like Nick here having issues with the font, the change in base font size itself being a problem, possible issues for the dyslexic, etc.

Comment: @AaronShekey This font change introduces difficulty for me to read the text on stack websites, specifically, the monospace font used on windows for syntax highlighting looks fat and is hard to read, the segue ui font as others have commented, looks like a comic sans-inspired design.  Why isn't this an option for users to decide to use?

Comment: Use **[this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364269/196424)** which is based on the Stylus browser plugin (very powerful).

Comment: **Chrome extension** to revert fonts (and other changes): https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/revert-stackexchange-form/fliedkodjpgomjmjbkaehhlllnhmcjnh

Answer (score 171):

Multi-disciplinary designer chiming in here.

> However, Arial doesn’t ship with Linux distros or Android devices. We’re currently only achieving consistency between macOS, iOS, and Windows, leaving 2 platforms to choose their system font.

Why are you not loading the Arial webfont?

> We’d rather have the consistency be shifted to the device itself—when viewing Stack Overflow on iOS, *it’ll feel that much more native* in San Francisco. Same with Android, which is already being displayed in Roboto.

What is the advantage of feeling more native? Is Stack Exchange not its own brand with its own identity?

> We should also note that prior to these changes, our monospace font stack varied wildly. Now you'll have better consistency between sans and monospace, since we'll do our best to choose the right pairings.

You can still select the right pairings going forward *and* have it be consistent across each platform.

> If consistency were the absolute goal, we’d ship our own custom font. I would love to be able to truly express our brand through a typeface, but that means users would have to download custom fonts and wait for them to display.

You can achieve consistency *without* making your own custom font. There are plenty of websites that download off-the-shelf well-designed fonts. Text is rendered and then styled, so even if there was a delay in loading the generally small (~100kb) font file, the text would be displayed in the default browser font temporarily—making it still readable as it doesn't require any "waiting" for the text itself to display. Regardless, the font file is downloaded once on first visit.

---

As a designer, this move baffles me. I use a Windows computer, an Android phone, and an iPad tablet and each one will look different from each other, but look native to the device they're on? I fail to see the real reason for this move. What is the advantage of looking native to a device? Has any other company done this (purposefully) and if so, what was the outcome? Do your designers on staff agree with this decision?

I'd love to hear any and all comments or thoughts.

Comment: Not a designer, but the move might be influenced as a replacement of native (web) app on mobile (since the official SO and SE mobile apps have been "sunset"), like [how Flutter decides the font for different OS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56339147/2821954).

Comment: [Also not a designer] Personally, if it makes things more legible I'm all for it. I remember when Ask Different used to have its own, very clean font; then a few years ago everything went to the same fuzzy font that Super User had been using. I'd like 'clean' back & if that's San Fransisco, then that will suit me just fine. I honestly don't care how it looks on Windows [nor do I imagine Windows users will care how it looks on Mac] Responsive design means it's going to look different on every screen anyway.

Comment: Currently there is a tension between achieving a consistent look for branding purposes and making the site look good. The version of Arial which Microsoft licensed for use as a web font is from 1996. It only has about 500 characters. The typeface itself is from 1982 when we used fuzzy CRT monitors. If they used that, then type quality would go down on millions of devices and scattered bits of text would be displayed in visually incompatible fallback fonts.

Comment: A fellow designer!  We have opted to not load webfonts at our scale. Stack Overflow, despite being one of the top 50 visited websites, is _fast_ and we'd like to keep it that way. Everything's a budget, right? We download CSS, JavaScript, and maybe eventually, fonts. We'd have to delete a lot of legacy CSS before we have the budget for fonts. For now, this allows us to modernize our typefaces.

Comment: Hard to address each of your questions, but lots of your questions are addressed in my original post. Our designers agree with this decision. Many websites, including what I consider our peers take this system typeface approach, GitHub being the closest audience we have.

Comment: Basically, they're following the train of others companies doing the same. On a personnal note, it's true that if each site I would visit had a distinct font, it might hurt my eyes to constantly switch from one font to another.

Comment: Another multidisciplinary designer chipping in :)

I second that performance and accessibility is more important than a unique brand. The logo, colours and URL do more than enough to carry the brand, and I wish more companies put a greater focus on creating value for the user rather than looking unique.

Comment: As a user, I couldn't give two shits about a "brand" and "identity", I just want to be able to read the code I'm copying and pasting

Comment: ^That, plus I want the rendering to be imperceptibly fast. The fonts swapping suddenly 100ms after the page loads is 100ms slower than I like.

Comment: @AaronShekey "modernize our typefaces" follows the Microsoft Way™ of change for change's sake. Not at all a fan of the Segway font (misspelling intentional). Looks really ugly now, just like all the default fonts in MS Office, which I promptly change. #NotADesigner Frankly, the Arial is far more clear and readable to my eyes.

Comment: *"generally small (~100kb) font file"* - That's not small, **at all**. And it adds another web request that's executed strictly in sequence, after the HTML has loaded and parsed, and after the CSS the HTML references has loaded and parsed. Plus, another point of failure. The web today as a whole feels as responsive as MySpace in its day. To fix that we need to convince designers to stop having an opinion on what's small or what's fast.

Comment: I don't mind loading fonts, but please, please, please don't give us Arial back. [I already mentioned this on the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021/364316#comment1214996_364048), and Arial is one of the unnecessarily many fonts where I and l are essentially identical. For me personally, that makes certain (largely abbreviations) impossible to read, because I have no idea if the I is meant to be an I or an l. There's a lot of talk about fonts being hard to read, but I'm surprised l vs I isn't mentioned more.

Comment: Fonts where l and I are identical rely so heavily on contextual reading for understanding the character that anywhere context fails, I have to switch to Vim (where I have a readable font set by default) and paste the text to have a chance of understanding what it's meant to say. Arial is a shitty font in that regard, but it's so wide-spread that the problem exists everywhere. If that problem can cease to exist on SO and SE, I'm happy. It currently has on my OS too (Mint, Ubuntu derivative using the Ubuntu font).

Comment: In an optimal world, we'd have a universal font where these edge-cases don't exist, that also plays nicely with unicode. In the meanwhile, Arial is a step in the opposite direction, not in a useful direction.

Comment: Agreed. This is an incredibly ham-fisted and nonsensical change. Fonts have been a browser setting (and thus **a user preference**) for as long as the web has existed. It's actively user-hostile to take that away from people, and value the company's preferences higher than the user's in this really subjective area. Anybody who wants their browser to look like their system settings dialog could set it to do exactly that before, there's no added value in forcing it. And personally I don't care how SO looks like on the next person's Linux box, the "consistency" take is completely bogus.

Comment: @Tomalak For the little it's worth, the question says: "Displaying custom fonts is getting more realistic every day at our scale, so we may revisit that choice at some point, and come back to a more consistent experience. System fonts let us modernize **in the meantime** without too many drawbacks." - this is a strong indicator that custom fonts are coming. The when is of course unknown.

Comment: @Zoe I'm not interested in a brand font, really. I'm also completely uninterested in "consistency" although I understand that someone at SO might be. As far as I am concerned, the personal preferences of someone at SO don't apply to me, and they should not overrule my own. There is a perfectly good font preference setting in my browser's options, and optimally, I'd like that to work.

Comment: This font change introduces difficulty for me to read the text on stack websites, specifically, the monospace font used on windows for syntax highlighting looks fat and is hard to read, the segue ui font as others have commented, looks like a comic sans-inspired design.  Why isn't this an option for users to decide to use?

Comment: The only positive thing about new fonts is that now you never know what you have copied until you paste it into code editor!

Comment: THANK YOU for this comment! An idea with good intent doesn't mean it's good. And more people need to reason it before acting. This shift if a major disappointment, which makes sense only from a very weird perspective. Using the site on various devices looks **amazingly awful**!

Comment: @PasserBy I vote for *fast...* Spare a thought for us who are 1,000s of miles away, gigabit ethernet is something we only read about on the internet. My broadband comes in on a wire across my neighbours garden and I live out in the sticks.  8-(

Comment: Any typographical decision involving Arial which isn't "stop using Arial" is the wrong decision and always has been; it's a garbage font. As has been pointed out, l, 1, and I should all be clearly differentiated by your font.

Comment: The font looks very smooth on MacOS. It will even increase the time I use SO. Nice Job!

Answer (score 156):

## Why Segoe UI? Why UI fonts at all?

Segoe UI is, as its name implies, a font designed for UI. As other posters have said, it is actually somewhat harder to read. The lines have a lower weight and the x-height is smaller. You need to change the font size or you'll reduce visibility and accessibility.

Though, honestly, UI fonts are not designed for reading larger amounts of text. Using `font-family: ui-font` makes the most sense when you are mimicking a window, so that the app looks more native, but not for large amounts of text.

This seems a move made without any concerns about accessibility. Users should have been told about the propose change well in advance and given a chance to voice possible flaws so that everything could be worked out. I do not understand why StackExchange continues to make decisions without taking advantage of one of its biggest assets: the combined knowledge and experience of so many subject-matter experts.

I suspect that this change is actually more of a fad than anything. Of course Github did it--they're owned by Microsoft. Microsoft, however, is historically not very good at design.

Comment: This is especially a problem for me since I'm dealing with the small monospace on Ubuntu that [others](/a/364275/343832) [have](/a/364272/343832) pointed out, and I use Chrome, which only lets you set `monospace`, not `ui-monospace` (because why would it?) in `chrome://settings/fonts`.

Answer (score 116):

## Update

As of "Update 3" things look about like they used to for me on Linux Mint, thank you for hearing the feedback and making the adjustments. (Took a quick look on Windows. I can't say it looks good to me. Better, but not good.)

The process part of the below remains pertinent, but again, thank you for listening.

---

## Two issues

1. The change is not good, it makes things **much** harder to read
2. The process of the change was awful

Apologies for being blunt below, but I'm cross I even have to write this. Has Stack Exchange learned nothing about community engagement and change management? And I'm in a hurry because I have actual work to do, so wordsmithing isn't a priority.

## The change itself is not good

This change makes it **really** hard to read the site on Brave (Chrome-like) on Linux Mint 20. This isn't a moving the cheese thing. This is actually making my eyes hurt.

The text seems smaller ("gee, thanks" says the 54-year-old man), line height and letterspacing is...off... I'm not a fonts guy so I don't know the ins and outs of why, but **even zooming the text to a reasonable size again it's still really hard to read** (and the layout gets hinky).

Sure, I could use a userscript to fix it, and then have to update that user script every time you make another change like this instead of fixing things that actually matter (like Stack Snippets), and deal with the inevitable bug — sometimes quite subtle bugs making you miss important information — related to using a userscript that you don't test with (why would you?) before doing updates.

**I should not have to do that just to help people on Stack Overflow.**

See the end of this post for pictures of how it looks on my system, but here's a side-by-side between now and May 6th (I suggest downloading and viewing at 100%):

[image]

I'm surprised to find that the `font-size` values didn't change (because it *seems* smaller), it's "just" the `font-family`. But it's a big negative impact on readability, on my system anyway.

Making large blocks of text readable online is surely a solved problem? Blog after blog has perfectly readable text (much more readable than mine; I need to fix it). News sites. Etc., etc., etc.

## The process of the change was awful

**Reading and writing text is what using Stack Exchange is all about.** Changing the text is a *huge* deal.

I visit Stack Overflow every day, several times a day. There was no advance warning of this change that I saw (if it was in the "The Overflow Blog" or "Featured on Meta" lists, pardon me for focussing on questions and answers — a change this big should be a banner I have to dismiss). I take it the only announcement of it was in the "Featured on Meta" list that I, like many, don't pay much attention to.

I was going nuts trying to figure out what button I'd accidentally pressed to screw up my text like this. Again, a banner was called for.

Maybe I'm not representative, though I see I'm far from alone with finding the new font harder to read.

Having used a proper process would at least reassure me that it was taken seriously and done properly even if it negatively impacts me personally. Here's an off-the-cuff of how this change could have been handled better IMHO (but I'm not a process consultant, it can probably be done even better):

### 1. Requirements: Is a change really needed?

Ask the users, in particular your regular power users: Do we need to change it, or is it fine as is?

### 2. Requirements: Why is a change needed? What needs changing? How?

Ask the users **why** they feel a change is needed, **what** needs changing, and **how**.

### 3. Implementation: Options

Do up mock pages showing:

- Original
- Option A
- Option B
- Option C
- Option D
- Option E

and collect feedback on the options, narrowing it to (say) two.

### 4. Implementation and Communication: A/B Testing

Announce the upcoming change and ask people to opt into being randomly assigned one of the test groups. Get feedback and measure engagement vs. previous levels of engagement. Be sure to get a representative sample testing (including young people, older people, people with "perfect vision," people who need corrective lenses, ...).

### 5. Implementation: Optional

A change this big is **never** going to be okay with everyone. Provide an opt out. Yes, it incurs maintenance cost (or more accurately, making the change incurs maintenance cost; leaving it alone wouldn't have cost anything). Review annually to see if you can retire the opt-out.

Or here's an idea: Have options. There is no one-size-fits-all. Offer a two or three presentations.

### 6. Implementation: Finalize

Finish the identified change without hundreds of `!important` CSS rules, not least so userscripts or similar can reasonably handle undoing it.

### 7. Communication: Advance warning

Banner-level warning of the upcoming change with a preview link so everyone can see what it will look like to them.

### 8. Communication: Notification

Banner-level notification the change has been put in place.

## Here's what it looks like

(please click to see the full size versions)

Question list - unzoomed:

[image]

Question - unzoomed:

[image]

Question list - zoomed 110%:

[image]

Question - zoomed 110%:

[image]

Question list - zoomed 125%:

[image]

Question - zoomed 125%:

[image]

Posting an answer - unzoomed:

[image]

Posting an answer - zoomed 110%:

[image]

Posting an answer - zoomed 125%:

[image]

Comments - unzoomed:

[image]

Comments - zoomed 110%:

[image]

Comments - zoomed 125%:

[image]

Comment: +3108 hurts most for me ;)

Comment: @Luuklag - LOL I haven't clicked it in a while, so it adds up... :-D

Comment: I'm a relatively young person and I am squinting at the screen to be able to read what that says.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm 58 years old. During the past few years, I've spent quite a few hours each day on various SE sites, especially Math SE. This was usually never a problem before for my eyes, but with this change I've had eye strain trying to read the text, especially on certain sites like the Math one (it's worse on this site too, but not as bad). The text is somewhat smaller and thinner, which makes it harder for me to read. I'll likely get used to this, or make some adjustments to make it easier for me, but I agree with your various points, especially about providing options to users.

Comment: This is beautifully thorough.

Comment: Some of the screen shots are not in focus!

Comment: @user59748 - LOL!

Comment: While I personally _like_ the Mac system font ( Mac user here) — actually, I don't dislike Segoe UI either — and therefore disagree with your first premise, nevertheless I voted you up since _a)_ I can say that what you guys get on Linux is not a good choice (too distracting, to say the least), _b)_ I quite appreciated your thorough analysis, and _c)_ like you, I completely missed the change announcement as well...

Comment: I'm 30 and I agree. I'm no longer able to keep a decent layout using two windows per monitor. Plus, Ubuntu fonts look hip and trendy. They feel out of place here and are just too distracting.

Comment: As a Windows user I find this change atrocious.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk - Yeah. I took a look at it on a VM (I mostly use Windows on VMs) and it was *okay* -- not good, just okay, readable *enough*. Just looked at it on a real machine and it seemed even a bit worse. :-|

Answer (score 76):

As you consider the font stack, please do consider revisiting [this very popular request: "Can we at least select our fonts?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307865/317948). Yes, it is marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), but the "[New plan is the old plan, mostly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311033/317948)" and these fonts are still inappropriate for a significant number of sites.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. As someone who is legally blind, but has some vision, Segoe UI has been the bane of my life since upgrading to Windows 10. I've sunk hours into doing whatever I can to get away from it because of how dreadful a font it is. I agree with @Davbog's answer. I don't care about whether something will "feel that much more native", I want to be able to read the content without straining my eyes doing so.

Comment: @JohnH I recently, to my delight, discovered [Atkinson Hyperlegible](https://brailleinstitute.org/freefont). So far, it and [Plex Sans](https://www.ibm.com/plex/) are the only sans-serif fonts (that I've found) featuring *both* slab-serif uppercase Ɪ and lowercase ɭ with a tail, allowing immediate stand-alone recognition without requiring the other character adjacent to be sure what | means.

Comment: Adam, that's really thoughtful of you to link those fonts - I appreciate that. I'll give them both a try and see how I get on.

Comment: Note that what they status-completed seems to be:  allow each *site* to customize its fonts.  What you seem to want if I'm reading the request correctly is to allow each *user* to customize the fonts.  It might be worth editing that into this suggestion so that it is more obvious if Stack employees read it.  Or if I'm misunderstanding, perhaps more explanation would help (it doesn't matter if I understand, but you don't want Stack employees to misunderstand).

Comment: @mdfst13 I think it is quite clear that the post speaks about *sites* wanting specific fonts. E.g. it says "Sites that use Unicode characters extensively, like Japanese.SE, will want" and "sites that need an alternate font".

Comment: Then I think that is why they are saying that it is completed.  They can set site-specific fonts.  If you want a font change for a specific site, you might be better off posting in that site's meta.  Because first you want to get community consensus on the site and then ask for a change to that specific site from Stack.  Getting community consensus on the common Meta doesn't ensure that the font will be correct for the specific site.  So customizations on a per-site basis should be discussed in each site's meta.

Comment: @mdfst13 Except such requests will be refused: "Themes can specify what elements use serif, sans-serif, or monospace fonts." i.e. not *which* fonts at all.

Comment: @JohnH … and I've now found a 3rd option: [Go fonts](https://blog.golang.org/go-fonts) ([Download](https://go.googlesource.com/image/+/master/font/gofont/ttfs/))

Comment: @Adám It's really good of you to link those to me. I'm still experimenting with the others, but this is very kind of you - thank you. I think I prefer the Go fonts already!

Comment: As a humble collector of fonts, my thanks to @Adám for Atkinson Hyperlegible and Plex Sans; both were promptly added to my collection. Thanks so much!

Regarding the issue under discussion, I wonder why SO didn't simply go with defining the default sans-serif font as, well, `sans-serif`. This will be replaced by whatever OS/browser font is set by default, and can freely be changed by the user (without tweaks, scripts, or any other 'tricks'). That's, AFAIK, what Wikipedia does.

Answer (score 66):

> Arial was first created in 1982, and has served the web well for *decades*. But technology moves on. Modern system typefaces look better on both new high DPI screens, and old screens alike. Apple’s San Francisco and Microsoft’s Segoe both look great on retina displays, have more expressive weights, and improve readability across all contexts.

To me, Segoe UI looks like a cartoon comic font. It's really bad, and unreadable. [And](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407551/why-changing-fonts-on-so/407552#comment842227_407551) [I](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407551/why-changing-fonts-on-so/407552#comment842230_407551) [am](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407551/why-changing-fonts-on-so/407552#comment842225_407551) [not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021/364287#comment1215686_364048) [alone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021/364287#comment1215728_364048) [in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021/364289#comment1215800_364048) [thinking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021/364287#comment1215805_364048) [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021/364287#comment1215094_364049).

Also, IMO Arial was perfectly readable on my HP 24mh monitor, with my Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti video card (this is new tech on the market). Yet the font is unreadable on this new technology. And I don't see any data that proves system typefaces look better than Arial on new devices.

Is there any paper which uses data collected from people that states that system fonts are more readable than Arial? Really, one of the only reasons this change was made was because GitHub did it.... :\

#### If you want to switch the font, please make it something other than Segoe UI for Windows.

Finally, *italics are a pain to read in the new font*.

Comment: Agreed that italics are worse as well. I focused on the smaller comment text, but the italics are even lighter. *Small fonts + italics is even worse.* I at least disable RGB rendering in Chrome, which makes things a bit better.

Comment: I guess I don't particularly mind it on Ubuntu (not terrible, not great) but I do have to agree that the reasoning behind it is bizarre. Not to get too deep into speculation, but it sounds like a designer at Github decided to make a token "modernization" gesture to change... something for the sake of "fashion" and SO just decided to copy it. Personally I'm all for websites honoring system fonts, but they didn't even do that properly, it doesn't honor *my system's* font, it uses the font SO thinks my system should be using, without really asking.

Comment: Also on an unrelated note, I would really personally prefer it if Github were not be treated as the world leader in where the rest of the internet would go. Ever since the Microsoft acquisition they've been making a bunch of changes (ranging from UI cheese moving to things that make life slightly better for enterprises sometimes but make it very annoying for smaller orgs). IMO, generally poorly thought out token gestures, always proclaimed with an air of "if it works for us, it works for everyone". If you're copying them, I'm not sure *they* know what they're doing, either.

Comment: @jrh yeah... I'm not an expert, but just because someone named Mark Otto wrote a blog post doesn't mean SE should change their font...

Comment: +1 for looking like a comic font. And this is on Debian, where apparently `system-ui` is [Cantarell](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Cantarell).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart IIRC you can change system fonts in debian (part of linux) I might be wrong, but give it a try.

Comment: @10Rep Why should a user want to change their system's fonts? If they can, and have, changed the system's fonts, it is because they like the systems UI when that font is used. Nobody should have to change their system to accommodate a website, or even a fiefdom of web sites. There are, of course, many other options to work around the issue depending on the user's technical skill with their OS, and their preference for something different, even if it's the "not different" that used to be here. The fact that there are already so many workarounds posted suggests that it's an unpopular change.

Comment: This font change introduces difficulty for me to read the text on stack websites, specifically, the monospace font used on windows for syntax highlighting looks fat and is hard to read, the segue ui font as others have commented, looks like a comic sans-inspired design.  Why isn't this an option for users to decide to use?

Comment: @Peter I've asked the same thing, and I was told by another user that I was acting entitled :(

Comment: Getting Cantarell here also (Fedora). No idea why; AFAICT neither my system nor browser specifies that font anywhere. It's... a rather strange looking font, compared to Liberation Sans which I was getting before.

Answer (score 48):

## Rapid observations

Interesting change. Confusing title. Strange timing.

---

### Interesting change

This looks to be a network-wide change, except when it isn't. Any site not already customized will switch to the new version, while customized sites get to keep what they have (or don't get the latest and greatest change). So long as the results are still readable, or no less readable than the current settings, it's fine. Telling the difference between uppercase /ˈaɪ/, lowercase /ˈɛl/ and Arabic numeral one can be difficult at a glance. Similar difficulties exists between uppercase /ˈoʊ/ and Arabic numeral zero. With luck the font served will resolve the issue.

### Confusing title

The term "system fonts" made me hopeful, at first. Thinking to myself that now whatever fonts I've set my system to use for serif, sans-serif and mono space would be used in my browser as well. Well, the title was promising in that regard. Rather, if the change works as intended, the site will use a font which my OS supposedly ships as the default "system" font. Well, for the "top five" anyway: Android, ChromeOS, Windows, MacOS, and iOS.

### Strange timing

Of all the things needing developer and designer attention on the network, this seems the least often mention, or requested, change. I've no idea how many sites have been out of Beta, or for how long, waiting on a customised theme, even a tiny bit to make them "unique" within the network. As mentioned in a comment, dark mode was introduced to SO over a year ago. Applying dark mode to the majority of the sites would seem to be less work than selecting and testing a new font stack system wide.

---

## What I think

(All in random order)

The "Why" section references a GitHub blog as covering the reasons for switching. The same blog entry explains why they dropped the Ubuntu font, yet it appears to be included in the font stack here. If GitHub had issues with that font using their modest, by comparison, site styling, what problems can be expected within this network?

The table of font to OS association contributed to my initial thought that the "system font" would be applied to the site. Using a custom font stack, which is supposed to have the site's fonts match the device's system font to create a seamless user experience only works until the user has selected a different font for their device. Worse, if the user *has* selected a different font they may be upset that SE refuses to acknowledge that choice.

Even if it's not a custom font for SE, though that was stated as a possibility in the future, using a downloadable font, with decent fallback options in the font stack seems like a better option for creating a "brand" feel rather than trying to create an "app" feel which is so demonstrably fragile. The wait for it to download, even on a mobile device should be minimal, and is likely cached by the device for future page loads as well.

Also interesting is the desire to modernize the style, but only for the sans-serif and mono space fonts. If the "old is bad and new is good" is to be part of the rationale, why leave the old serif fonts untouched? Times and Times New Roman (1931) are older than Arial (1982), and Georgia (1993) is not much newer.

As mentioned earlier, the differences between uppercase /ˈaɪ/, lowercase /ˈɛl/ and Arabic numeral one can be difficult at a glance, as can the difference uppercase /ˈoʊ/ and Arabic numeral zero. Finding a set of fonts, especially in the mono space group, would probably do more for the users than aiming to update the fonts just because the current set is "old".

I frequently see references to the design system (Stacks), and how much easier it makes design change implementations. In this case because the font stacks can be stored as CSS variables. Somehow, whenever other, user desired, design changes are mentioned, the typical reply is akin to the idea that it's too hard, or take too much time, or involved too many resources. I've yet to decide if the Stacks took is helpful or not, in actual application by the team.

---

I'm not opposed to a fresh new look. It's even a good thing to keep a fresh feel to the site. I also do not personally care which fonts are used, or even if serif or sans-serif is the norm. The timing, while short, isn't a problem, nor would it be if there had been no notice at all. Odds are that less than half the users will even notice the change. I am a bit surprised that this change was not significant in requests or complaints on meta yet seems to have been fully developed without feedback from users.

It's my hope that the reading won't be any more difficult than it is.

Comment: "*seems to have been fully developed without feedback from users*" - unfortunately, that's how things are done these days. I'm saying this considering the last design changes ([this](/q/343919/401803) and [this](/q/353446/401803), just to mention 2 examples) - and regardless of all the negative feedback and requests to revert them ([here](/a/353529/401803) and [here](/q/344874/401803)), SE kept those changes, ignoring the community. That's their current *modus operandi*, unfortunately our opinion doesn't make any difference to them.

Comment: The font used will actually be [`system-ui`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family#syntax). This *should* be whatever you set as your system font, if the OS allows that. So exactly what you wanted, if I understood you correctly. The new CSS does *not* hard-code font names.

Comment: Oh I wish it were easier to address things via comments. There exists the concept of quick wins on decades-old software, and this is one of them. Making themes and ensuring they're all dark-mode aware is not a quick win. It'd take me about 10 months to do, exclusively, and that assumes those changes have the largest impact.

Comment: @KonradRudolph If the design does use `system-ui` the results will be nearly identical to what they don't want, Helvetica and Arial defaults. My current desktop uses Noto Sans and my browser is set for Source Sans Pro. The page you directly linked to explaing `system-ui` still selects Arial. https://i.stack.imgur.com/GElc0.png

Comment: @Chindraba No, you’re misunderstanding computed style in the screenshot. The `arial` value is being *overridden* by the cascading style value `system-ui`. And the selected text in your screenshot is very clearly *not* using Arial.

Comment: @AaronShekey "Modern" is not automatically a win, quick or otherwise. The only thing I see here even *approaching* an actual reason is some vague mention of high resolution devices and ill-defined notions of "readability." I don't see any specification of what problem you're actually solving, just common, vague platitudes that tend to create more trouble instead of solving problems. But your comment is a cop out, anyway. You have a whole question post to explain the issues you only reference here and chose not to.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I stand corrected, it is picking up on my browser's setting and using that. The "system" is set to Noto Sans, and the browser is Source Sans Pro, which is the final font used to display that segment. The on-device consistency is still lost, and the user is given more control. +1 for the user wishes, -1 for designer wishes.

Comment: Moving forward without feedback from users seems to be part of the Stack DNA.

Comment: @AaronShekey Please confirm whether the claim `font-family: system-ui` will be used is correct. If not, then addons exist that will allow users to change any custom font, which might help alleviated concerns about the changes. Personally, I don't like that Segoe-UI has a smaller x-height, which will necessitate zooming in further on the site to be able to read the comments.)

Comment: @trlkly The update to the post, beginning with "Here’s the exact font stack we’ve specified that’ll go live on the 10th." was made by AaronShekey. With the time left before it goes live, I'd have to take that as confirmation of what the font stack is. Aaron might reply here, but until then I'd take it as official anyway.

Comment: @Chindraba It didn't seem to follow my browser settings on Firefox, I had to uncheck "Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of your selections above" to change the fonts. I'm glad I found that checkbox though, this is nice.

Comment: @jrh I started to do some testing to see which settings caused what results. Using Chrome, FF and FF-Dev on openSUSE Linux. Decided it wasn't important enough to see exactly what results were possible. Without the force-fonts active it seems that on FF and FF-Dev `system-ui` uses the browser's selected sans font while Chrome uses the font specified in system settings. `ui-monospace` in FF, FF-Dev and Chrome use the browser's setting. Serif fonts have been ignored since it's using a defined stack rather than a generic name anyway.

Comment: @Chindraba personally I was hoping to use a serif font for everything, I don't really like sans serif fonts for anything because 0/O I/l/| look very similar. You could say that in the context that it matters, people should be using `backticks` `(I/l/|, O/0)` but it doesn't always happen and even in the editor I'd prefer to just have a more distinct font. I was hoping that SO would pick up on the fact I set all of my system fonts in my OS (Ubuntu Mate) to something different, but it didn't.

Comment: @jrh Try setting the browser's font selections. Haven't tried it but FF has 4 settings in the "Advanced..." dialog: Proportional, Serif, Sans-serif, and Monospace. Not sure when the Proportional setting is used, but the others don't _have_ to be set to matching fonts. You can set a serif font in the sans-serif selection.

Comment: @AaronShekey - *"There exists the concept of quick wins on decades-old software"* Yes. This isn't one of those. This is a quick loss. It's unfortunate that SE didn't consult users before doing it, but please listen to the feedback you're now getting. UI fonts are for **user interface elements**, not blocks of text.

Answer (score 48):

I don’t like this at all. Here is a UserStyle to revert:

```css
/* ==userstyle==
@name Stack Exchange
@namespace Steven Penny
@version 1.0.0
==/userstyle== */
@-moz-document
domain("stackexchange.com"),
domain("stackoverflow.com"),
domain("superuser.com") {
   body {
      --ff-mono: Consolas;
      --ff-sans: Arial;
   }
   .topbar-dialog .modal-content .message-text h4,
   .topbar-dialog,
   header {
      font-family: var(--ff-sans) !important;
   }
   .full-diff .content,
   .wmd-input,
   code {
      font-family: var(--ff-mono) !important;
   }
}
```

https://github.com/openstyles/stylus

Comment: Can this be put right into Firefox userContent.css or does require some extension?

Comment: @raj [Install Stylus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/) - create a new style, paste code above, give it name, save.

Comment: Sorry, technie ignoramus here. The new font is killing my eyes on History SE. Can someone explain how I can use this UserStyle posted here so I can revert? I have chrome, Windows 10.

Comment: @LarsBosteen same here - what you have to do is install stylus in the link J... gave. Then open that extension and copy this stylesheet into the extension. A userscript manager wouldn't work unfortunately.

Comment: To make this work on Linux, change `--ff-mono: Consolas, "Ubuntu Mono";`

Comment: **Chrome extension** to revert fonts (and other changes): https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/revert-stackexchange-form/fliedkodjpgomjmjbkaehhlllnhmcjnh

Answer (score 47):

**Update**: If you encounter this error in Chrome, turning on the "Use hardware acceleration when available" setting should solve this issue.

Code blocks in deleted posts are practically unreadable on Windows 10 (Chrome, 200% DPI).

[image]

Comment: That is really worse.

Comment: Well this most definitely is _not_ supposed to happen. What in the world is going on here? Can you tell me what font that's rendering in? Browser? Looks like Windows of course but something has gone off the rails here.

Comment: @AaronShekey The font seems to be Cascadia Mono. Windows 10.0.19042.928, Chrome 90.0.4430.212

Comment: What are your clear type settings? Do you have Windows Terminal installed, or did you install Cascadia Mono directly?

Comment: @AaronShekey Yes I have the Windows Terminal Preview installed. I don't remember installing Cascadia Mono separately. ClearType is turned on.

Comment: I'm really struggling to reproduce this issue. Anyone else got any repro steps here?

Comment: @AaronShekey It doesn't do it in Edge so it seems like something specific to Chrome. I have verified that it does it in an Incognito window as well which suggests it's not related to any extensions I have installed. It's probably some particular Chrome setting, but how to tell which one?

Comment: @JonathanPotter Have you tried toggling the "Use hardware acceleration when available" setting?

Comment: @ChrisO Bingo! This was turned off; turning it on fixes the problem. I guess this makes it a Chrome bug rather than an issue with SO's font usage.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Glad to see the problem fixed.  Turning HW acceleration ON or OFF sometimes fixes (or causes) strange errors with the various browsers, at least on Windows, which is my main experience these days.  Could definitely be a Chrome bug, or Chrome is just doing something unusual that exposes a bug/quirk in DirectX or the display driver.  Sometimes updating Windows or the display driver can fix these issues (or cause others ;- ) not that I'm jaded).  <== That's a lie, I'm totally jaded, why the Bleep does MS think HW acceleration is beneficial for rendering fonts? </rant>

Comment: Oh I am _so glad_ y'all figured this one out. This one had me absolutely stumped.

Comment: Ahhah, that looks like Turbo Pascal under MS-DOS we've used at school!... =D Sorry for laughing at your problem, but this made my day...

Comment: Turning off "Use hardware acceleration when available" is not a good solution... HW acceleration speeds up rendering considerably by offloading tasks like scrolling, scaling, blending, as well as all SVG and canvas rendering, to the GPU. The issue is that Segoe UI is a crappy font to begin with. Before the change SO used Arial on Windows, and that one obviously worked perfectly, also with HW acceleration on.

Answer (score 45):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

I currently use SE on multiple devices, with multiple OS' (Windows, Mac OS, Android). Personally I would prefer a uniform site on all these devices, also as not to break my muscle memory (seeing that text will change in length buttons will inadvertently shift in the layout).

I know that you decided different, which is a great option for users using a single device. But at the same time SE also has the history of being highly customizable using one's profile. It would be great to have such a setting for the font as well. That way we can override the system font with a font of our picking. This would also be a great feature for those that have less then perfect eyesight and want to use a more accesible font.

Comment: Whilst certainlyna solution fornthe more tech-savvy users I think a profile option would be far more user friendly. But this is indeed very much a "nice-to-have". @ColleenV

Comment: @ColleenV The problem with using the browser's settings to override the fonts is that it is universal. Without getting into user scripts and other super-tech tricks, either the users accepts ugly fonts on some some sites so they can see beautiful sites when they visit them, or they pick a fixed set of fonts for everything and never see the beauty the Web has to offer. Why shouldn't SE strive to be part of the "beauty" rather than encourage users to override your choices?

Comment: *"But at the same time SE also has the history of being highly customizable using one's profile."* i mean.... has it though? all we can do there is hide a few ads. Adblock is far more effective.

Comment: @user400654 See https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/me

Comment: Oh, right, they let us disable a few of their other mistakes

Answer (score 38):

I see a lot of people are upset about the change, particularly Windows folks. Who would've thought Microsoft's Segoe is not a great typeface... :)

My question to the team is: Why not simply this?

```css
@ff-sans: sans-serif;
@ff-serif: serif;
@ff-mono: monospace;
```

Browsers allow everyone to easily set their preferred default, serif, sans-serif, and monospace fonts directly in the settings. It allows them to render text in every supported language using the most appropriate and readable font. Users with dyslexia can pick fonts that help them read, without having to install extensions.

On Windows, people may be used to Arial because, at least in Firefox, Arial is in fact the default `sans-serif` font.

If you truly want everyone to have a fast, coherent user experience appropriate for their device and needs, I think it makes more sense to use the standard font family specifiers. I'm not saying that Arial is better (IMO it's about as bad as Segoe), nor that every system has a great preset of default fonts (Windows sure doesn't), but if an experience consistent with the user's environment is what you're after, this is one sure way to get there.

Comment: I'm really glad that _someone_ posted exactly the reply I was typing! I was just going to add the following points:

- Most modern browsers will allow users to change their _browser_ fonts independently of the _system_ fonts, so, if you happen to hate your OS font, you can select your favourites instead;
_and_
- Wikipedia apparently uses this approach; since most discussions have revolved around GitHub vs. SO/SE, why not take a look at what Wikipedia did — a site which, in spite of everything, is still ranked at #13 (according to Wikipedia and Alexa), well above SO's #48...

Comment: This is going to be devastating on several Linux distros with at least some browsers (e.g. Firefox) where the default Sans(/Serif) font is DejaVu Sans(/Serif), which is about 20% larger than normal. There are specific reason on why system font stacks are used on most "big" (and small) websites, a few are already discussed by OP.

Answer (score 33):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Could you pretty-please not hardcode any of the following CSS selectors with the new `font-family` and actually use the `--ff-*` CSS variables without `!important` everywhere like you promised? Thanks.

Compiled from [https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/primary.css](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/primary.css?v=d81f84368fef):

- `code`
- `pre`
- `textarea.wmd-input,textarea#wmd-input`
- `.topbar-dialog`
- `.topbar-dialog .header h3`
- `.topbar-dialog .header h3 a`
- `.topbar-dialog .modal-content .message-text h4`
- `.topbar-dialog .pinned-site-editor-container .remove-pinned-site-link a`
- `.top-bar`
- `#user-menu`
- `.full-diff .content`

[image: hardcoded font-family in .topbar-dialog CSS class]

Comment: Now my userstyle is just as bloated as SE's hardcoded selectors :(

Comment: There's even more than just the ones that I listed, but they target close icons so I didn't feel as strongly about including them.

Comment: As you can imagine, we have a lot of legacy CSS that is way over-specified. More and more of our app will rely on the `--ff` variable as we continually refactor.

Comment: @AaronShekey maybe refactor first, instead of pushing out a half finished product?

Comment: @StevenPenny lol working on it!

Comment: I'm shocked. I just did a simple search on the two main CSS files and found 3,260 uses of `!important`. All included in only 5,638 rules; better than one `!important` for two rules. To me that seems like a major _code smell_. Refactoring might be too late. Perhaps it'd be faster to rebuild from scratch with a solid design concept at the root.

Comment: @AaronShekey I came here to express my frustration at how hard it is to use [unix.se] on my Arch system since the font change. But having seen the completely professional way you've dealt with some, ehm, less than politely phrased criticism here, even cheerfully responding to Steven's [needlessly snarky comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/?cb=1#comment1215863_364273), all I want to say is "wow, thanks for being such a good sport!" (OK, and others have made my whiny points for me already, so I can stay on my high horse and enjoy the view).

Comment: @Chindraba I know that feel, trust me.

Comment: @AaronShekey The "main" site `stackexchange.com` is still *not* using CSS `var()` for fonts. There's an extra `font-family` on `html, body` that bypasses the variables.

Comment: @iBugsaysReinstateMonica `stackexchange.com` isn't fully powered by our front-end library Stacks, if you can believe it. Hardcoded for now. It'll take some doing to point it to our single source of truth. 

Comment: @AaronShekey This is super late, but `.full-diff .content` still has a hardcoded font-family (as can be seen in 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/Content/Sites/stackoverflowmeta/primary.css)

Answer (score 29):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The highlight surrounding OP's username in a comment overlays parts of the comment's text.

[image: Example in dark-mode]

[image: Example in light mode]

*<sup>Windows, Chrome 64-bit</sup>*

Comment: Yeah... in the second scenario it could've been "aqqresive"... you really can't see it.

Comment: I'm seeing this effect with code (due to the grey highlighting) in comments as well (Firefox on Ubuntu with Cascadia font)

Comment: Line height is just extremely improper for this kind of stuff. Not to mention reading longer texts..

Comment: This _should_ be improved now.

Answer (score 28):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I guess someone must [really hate me](https://xkcd.com/1015/).

[image: Bad kerning Roboto font]

This is Firefox ESR 78 on Debian picking Roboto. A font badly hinted and even worse kerned, at this DPI at least. And I think I liked the look of Arimo more anyway… (My actual UI font is Noto Sans Display SemiCondensed, which looks better, but I still wouldn’t want it here. I never bothered installing Ubuntu fonts.)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oUn4.jpg

Comment: Mark actually mentions this in his post on systems fonts, saying "Roboto messes with certain Linux installs". If we remove Roboto, it should still load where we want it to. What happens if you delete Roboto from the font stack, what loads instead?

Comment: @AaronShekey Noto Sans, which looks passable I guess, but still rather blurry on low-DPI screens like mine — and those are still common, mind you.

Comment: Looking into this one. I'm on a low-DPI screen too 

Comment: Related: *[Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208)*

Comment: @user3840170 this should be addressed in the latest round of changes. Debian _should_ be choosing DejaVu or Liberation Sans now.

Answer (score 24):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**Could you increase the default font size of Ubuntu Mono?**

This font is known to display about 2 points smaller than most other monospace fonts ([as commented on here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800424/why-are-ubuntu-mono-letters-so-small), and [discussed further here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-font-family/+bug/1860251)). It would be great is SE accounted for this and increased the size with 2 points instead of the current setting which makes monospace text on the Linux version of SE is harder to read because it is so small.

Yes, it is possible to change all font sizes in your browser settings, but the issue here is specific to Ubuntu Mono and there is no way to control that from your browser settings (and the default SE UI should be made accessible on all platforms).

Here is an example of how small the font is when writing this post (compare to the rendered version):

[image]

On SO it appears even smaller and it is quite difficult to read without squinting which makes for a less than ideal user experience.

[image]

Comment: The font-size for normal text is okayish (imho a little bit too big), but the font-size for code is too small. Direct comparison of the new vs the old font: https://imgur.com/a/0mzGzyq

Comment: Also in [Zanna's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021/364272#364272).

Comment: This would help, but Ubuntu mono isn't just too small imho, it's really too narrow. Characters like `/` look really uncomfortable

Comment: Updated the original post to consider dropping `Ubuntu` as a font entirely. It's being considered in this [Stacks pull request](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/642).

Comment: Thanks for listening to our feedback @AaronShekey, really appreciate it! Personally I only have a problem with the size and I really like Ubuntu Mono when it is bumped up two sizes (this is what I run on my local terminals), but I understand that there might be other issues raised here and I am happy with any solution that makes the code chunks easier to read, thanks again!

Comment: Ok, we're off of Ubuntu Mono. It was a worthy endeavor, but for now, we've spec'd `Liberation Sans` and `Liberation Mono`. If you don't have those (Chrome installs them), you'll get whatever your browser chooses for `sans-serif` and `monospace`. Most likely DejaVu ✌️

Answer (score 23):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

I don't understand why you used the `system-ui` font for the default, instead of `sans-serif`. That font is not adjustable, and you are stuck with whatever horror the underlying OS chooses.

On Windows I also have some options to adjust rendering of the standard UI ([ClearType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType)), to make it more readable, but browsers use their own settings.

I don't know about other browsers, but Chrome allows customizing fonts that will be used for `sans-serif`, `serif`...

An additional issue is font size. On older Windows, the default font size was 8 points, but with introduction of Segoe UI that size changed to 9 points, because Segoe UI is harder to read on smaller sizes.

I don't have an issue with larger fonts that also use darker color, but small fonts with low contrast are impossible to read.

If you don't want to switch to `sans-serif` then at least increase the size and contrast of the smallest fonts - like in tags and also increase their contrast.

---

Using user scripts is simply not an option for the vast majority of users.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364368/657768 I'm so glad that several people actually think in the same way! Note that Wikipedia seems to have adopted that very same approach...

Answer (score 22):

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

Can you consider adding "Segoe UI Variable Text" before "Segoe UI" in the font stack for Windows?

Microsoft will gradually update Windows UI with this new font in the future: [Announcing Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 21376 | Windows Insider Blog](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2021/05/06/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-21376/)

> We are introducing Segoe UI Variable which includes an optical axis so that font outlines can scale seamlessly from small to larger display sizes. Segoe UI Variable is a refreshed take on the classic Segoe, now with improved legibility at small sizes, and much improved outlines at display sizes.
>
> Historically, fonts for printing small text were designed differently than fonts designed for large display text. Segoe UI was originally designed to work at 9pt, which makes it a great font for that size, but limits expression at large sizes and lacks legibility at even smaller sizes. Segoe UI Variable solves this by using a new version of Segoe that uses variable font technology to dynamically offer great legibility at very small sizes, and style at large sizes.

Segoe UI:

[image]

Segoe UI Variable:

[image]

Comment: Addressing your edit: AFAICT, the font name is just "Segoe UI Variable". It contains neither the word "Text" nor "Display".

Comment: @41686d6564 there are [multiple fonts](https://i.imgur.com/0OTD8sf.png) in "Segoe UI Variable" family that's why I wrote the full name, but, yeah, maybe it's not relevant.

Comment: I'll look into this, thanks for bringing it up @Swisstone.

Comment: @Swisstone What's the CSS name for Segoe UI Variable, is it just "Segoe UI Variable"? I'll have to opt into early releases to test this properly.

Comment: @Aaron Shekey: It's "Segoe UI Variable". It is a separate family from Segoe UI.

Comment: @AaronShekey well, the "Font Family" in Windows is "Segoe UI Variable", but, with CSS this is not recognized. I had to append one of the font's styles ("Display", "Small" or "Text") I chose "Segoe UI Variable Text" in my example but I can't tell if this is how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 22):

## Custom Fonts User Script: Revert or Improve the Font Updates

([Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/8932/custom-fonts-user-script-revert-or-improve-the-font-updates))

For those of you who prefered the old appearance, or would like a different font to appear in code blocks or across the site as a whole, Custom Fonts is a user script I wrote this morning to allow just that.

#### Features

Custom Fonts allows rules to be set for different sites, which can specify a sans serif, serif, and monospace font. A default can also be specified, allowing you to choose between sans serif and serif for any site.

Custom Fonts initially doesn't change anything (unless you download one with a preset), but on lines 26 and 27 are rules that revert all of Stack Exchange to its original fonts (once un-commented). Custom rules can be written, and there is a short reference in the comments under the `Rules` object.

#### Download

Custom Fonts is a user script, meaning that it requires Greasemonkey (Firefox or browsers that support Firefox extensions) or Tampermonkey (Chrome or browsers that support Chrome extensions) to be installed.

**[Custom Fonts 1.2.4](https://github.com/RedwolfPrograms/userscripts/raw/main/custom-fonts.user.js)**

**[Custom Fonts 1.2.4, with original fonts](https://gist.github.com/RedwolfPrograms/35c237ee02015b60d643f61a6f2570a1/raw/411d70cf08dca4c6d21003cad81915ca698bcf78/custom-fonts-1.2.4-arial.user.js)**

**[Custom Fonts 1.2.4, with Roboto + Roboto Mono](https://gist.github.com/RedwolfPrograms/6587a7fb499a43e72d4ec24f4dc42df0/raw/296fcf46451326b13aa26a534fbf2623758c0ff7/custom-fonts-1.2.4-roboto.user.js)**

Comment: The script isn't working for stackexchange.com.

Comment: @DavidPostill Interestingly, it seems the script is running, but the site just doesn't use the `--ff-sans` variable there. That means the problem will exist for any of the scripts and userstyles currently available I think :/

Comment: It's very annoying :) Everything else looks amazing. Great script!

Comment: @DavidPostill Now that I noticed that it's annoying and I needed to clean up some minor bugs anyway, so I fixed it :p

Comment: I think the 'main' stack exchange site... ironically...  might not be on stacks yet.

Comment: **Chrome extension** to revert fonts (and other changes): https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/revert-stackexchange-form/fliedkodjpgomjmjbkaehhlllnhmcjnh

Answer (score 17):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

We shouldn't assume that `system-ui` corresponds to Segoe UI font on Windows.

For example, if your system language is set to Simplified Chinese, the default font would be Microsoft YaHei UI; if the language is set to Japanese, the default font would be Meiryo UI. And both of these fonts look unbalanced when displaying Latin characters.

The worst part is that the system default font cannot be changed without completely messing up all the localized texts in the system.

Here's a comparison between old Arial font (right) and new `system-ui` (left) which is Microsoft YaHei UI on my PC:[image: comparison between fonts]

So I suggest to place `"Segoe UI"` before `system-ui` or really anything that can ensure that it never falls back to `system-ui` on Windows.

Comment: Got it! I was using Firefox for testing, mostly, and it seems there's a discrepancy between it and Chrome. I switched my Windows machine's language to Simplified Chinese and everything's rendering in Segoe UI with or without `system-ui` in Firefox. Chrome shows Microsoft YaHei UI, which doesn't seem to be the _worst_ thing, given we're trying to show system fonts. I'll bail on `system-ui` in the meantime. Also, very small sidenote: you can give this feedback without assuming I'm _quite ignorant_. 

Comment: Now... how do I get back to English lololol 

Comment: *cough* windows sandbox *cough*

Comment: @JourneymanGeek *cough* Would you mind sharing how to make Windows Sandbox run in another language?

Comment: Ah snap. I figured you could set the system-ui font for testing but I guess not. My bad. I'll take some cough drops now ._.

Comment: Please stop coughing, there's a pandemic!

Comment: The proposed change to drop `system-ui` is in this [Stacks pull request](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/642) that'll likely merge. I've updated my main post to include your feedback here. Any additional thoughts?

Comment: I believe Microsoft YaHei UI is backed by Segoe UI for Latin (and other western) scripts. MS YH UI is an Asian font family that does nothing special to Latin etc.

Comment: @iBugsaysReinstateMonica [comparison between the two fonts](https://i.imgur.com/lM3OzKT.png) on http://webfont-test.com

Comment: We've dropped `system-ui` as of update 3, so I think this should be addressed.

Answer (score 16):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) / Chrome / Stack Overflow - The new font and font-size makes it harder to read both plain text and code.

Why is the text in the new code blocks so tiny?

#### Before

<sup>(*with a user-script to get the old darker background in code blocks and spacing between lines*)</sup>

[image]

#### After:

<sup>(*with all user-scripts disabled*)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Even disregarding size, longer text is quite difficult to read in the new font.

Comment: FWIW a review of the font on https://www.designbombs.com/best-google-fonts-how-to-use-them/: "Ubuntu is the default font used in the popular Linux-based operating system of the same name. This font is a great choice for titles and headings, especially for blogs and magazine. **But it’s not a good choice for body text.**" (emphasis mine).

Comment: @Marijn Thanks! What I feel is _really_ odd is that SE made a special effort for Ubuntu and yet, using nothing but the default settings, it looks terrible. The combination of using Ubuntu 20.04 and Chrome on Stack Overflow surely can't be _that_ unusual. I described my poor eyesight in my [Request for a possibility to adjust the spacing between lines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353536/request-for-a-possibility-to-adjust-the-spacing-between-lines) and this is a second blow in a very short time. I now get tired in my eyes _really_ fast compared to just a few days ago... :-(

Comment: It looks even worse on my Arch. Code is almost illegible. I don't understand why they wanted to break something that has been working perfectly well for years.

Comment: Considering dropping `Ubuntu` as a font entirely in this [Stacks PR](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/642). What'cha think?

Comment: @AaronShekey That sounds promising. I'm not sure how to use the deploy preview tool though. Can I use it to put a _before_ and _after_ rendering of the pages next to each other?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Load up a page like this from [prod](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/prose/) (before), and this one from [staging](https://deploy-preview-642--stacks.netlify.app/product/components/prose/) (after)

Comment: @AaronShekey Thanks! I will try it at work where I have the unfortunate combo mentioned in the post. Can the same tool be used to actually use SO with my preferred settings (which is what my first post about spacing between lines was about)?

Comment: @AaronShekey thanks for taking the feedback into account. I would be in favor of dropping the Ubuntu font. It is rather wide so the question list has a lot more line breaks now. And code is tiny. I guess it is more a UI font than a text font.

Comment: @AaronShekey I've now had a look and to me, the staging version is absolutely _much_ better for code blocks.

Comment: Ok, we're back to `Liberation Sans` and `Liberation Mono` on most Linux distros. But Linux is Linux, and who knows what font pack you installed (and forgot about) sometime in 2018. 

Comment: @AaronShekey Great! Can't wait to see how this looks in Ubuntu / Chrome. I just noticed that the font became very large in code blocks when using Windows / Chrome @ Stack Overflow. It _should_ suit my bad eyes - but now very few characters fit horizontally. /Ted - Never happy :-)

Comment: Example: Code in old posts, carefully crafted to not go outside of the visual area of the code blocks, now does. Having to scroll horizontally when reading code isn't nice.

Comment: @AaronShekey It looks better in Ubuntu / Chrome again (I have a rather fresh installation with no extra font packs installed) - but not as good as it did before the extra spacing between lines was introduced.

Answer (score 15):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

**[Please bring back the old line-height 1.3 setting](/q/353525/350567)**

I find new fonts (I'm on Windows, so Segoe UI) look even worse with the current settings. It's more comfortable to read with thinner fonts at more compact line heights.

Screenshot for current (1.5):

> [image: LH 1.5]

Screenshot for `line-height: 1.3`

> [image: LH 1.3]

Comment: Just to offer an opposing point of view, I find your 1.5x line-height screenshot more readable. 1.3x looks cramped. And to put this statement into context: I am hawkish about not wasting vertical space for code readability, and I consciously broke my University’s rule when submitting my PhD thesis because I refused to adhere to their overly large line spacing requirements. So I’m certainly not biased towards large line spacing.

Comment: (And if we’re bikeshedding, I’d prefer a *slightly* tighter spacing than 1.5 with the specific typeface and line length in the screenshots. But I’d also prefer properly typeset, justified paragraphs and no modern browser can do this properly so it’s not happening.)

Comment: I agree with you, but unfortunately I believe this won't happen. SE simply ignored the request you linked (despite all the upvotes) and did whatever they wanted to do, regardless of what the community said. A middle term was also suggested (put that in preferences and let everybody chooses whatever line height they want), but even that was completely ignored. All the recent design changes was unilaterally made, ignoring any community's feedback. Therefore, the only alternative that's left to us are [userscripts](/a/353605/401803) (mine is called "_fix crap layout_", BTW)

Comment: I personally prefer the larger line heights. Also reduces line height unevenness when there is [tag:tag-markup] in post text, as that requires more vertical space.

Comment: @hkotsubo Saying that SO ignored the request is flat out false. In fact, the new design used a 1.6x spacing and in response to the request SE changed the spacing to 1.5x (and changed it further for monospaced fonts to make box art work). Maybe you’re still not happy with that but it’s unfair and unnecessary to lie about SO responding to the request.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Let's see: they changed to 1.6, people complained and asked to revert back to 1.3, they changed to not-so-terrible-but-still-bad 1.5 - perhaps they didn't "ignore", but didn't listen anyway, doing something they thought it could be a solution (but it's not what was requested). So let's just say they partially ignored (just pretended to listen the community, but in the end kept their decision to increase line height). But that's just for line height, because in the case of blockquotes, they completely ignored the request to revert the change.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Fair enough, but what about all the people who upvoted the request to revert back to 1.3? Or the suggestions to put this in user preferences (which would make everyone happy)? Anyway, it's pointless to continue discussing it, as SE probably won't change this, and keep doing whatever they want (I wonder if community feedback still matters, because based on the last changes, it seems that it doesn't). Anyway, I'll just keep using my userscripts (not the ideal solution, but still better than relying on SE's design decisions)

Comment: @hkotsubo those were meta users, the only users opinions' who matter are those who get "randomly" picked in the surveys on SO main.

Answer (score 14):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

OMG, MY EYES !!!

---

The new MacOS fonts are very "slim" and they are very hard to read when the color is not black (eg: blueish or grayish).

Please, consider reverting this change until more research is being done and more issues are fixed.

---

Updating to system font would have been totally normal move, IF:

- those fonts would have been readable.

The font (as of Thu, May 13th) is abysmal on MacOS (usually the OS that designers use), and there is no reason to expect them being any better on other platforms.

Especially painful:

- linked posts on the right sidebar:
  [image]
- comments:
  [image]
- homepage:
  [image]

Comment: This is related to macOS 11.3's treatment of font smoothing, or the lack thereof. Prior to 11.3, you could change this at the OS-level, but now you can't. I've made the [choice](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/commit/c8569513beb949daf7d93b305c94a56de5274488) in our library to remove the super thick font-smoothing, but can revisit this choice. Half of y'all will hate it. Half will [love it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316797/355163). Super tricky now that the _user_ can't choose at the OS-level.

Comment: how are your eyes doing now after this third update?

Comment: much better, thanks !

Answer (score 13):

Here's a userstyle I threw together that should fix both sans-serif and monospace. It also fixes hardcoded fonts within textareas and codeblocks that don't use the font variables for some reason. This should work in both Stylus (tested) and Stylish (untested).

```css
@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com"), domain("stackexchange.com"), domain("askubuntu.com"), domain("superuser.com"), domain("serverfault.com"), domain("stackapps.com"),
domain("mathoverflow.net") {
body {
    --ff-sans: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    --ff-mono: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace, sans-serif;
}

code, .s-prose code, pre.s-code-block, textarea.wmd-input, textarea#wmd-input, .full-diff .content {
    font-family: var(--ff-mono);
}

.top-bar, .topbar-dialog, #user-menu, .topbar-dialog .header h3 a, .topbar-dialog .pinned-site-editor-container .remove-pinned-site-link a, .topbar-dialog .modal-content .message-text h4 {
    font-family: var(--ff-sans) !important;
}
}
```

https://gist.github.com/SuperStormer/60a5e5c7e9549e9ed865a579df6f11be

Comment: Can it be put right into Firefox userContent.css, without any extension?

Comment: It *should* work, though I haven't tested it.

Comment: I needed to add `!important` at the end of each style declaration to make it work in userContent.css. Thanks!

Comment: I also changed the font in the top bar of the site back to sans-serif by adding: `.top-bar, .topbar-dialog { font-family: var(--ff-sans) !important;
}`

Comment: Great, works in stylebot too :) You saved my day :)

Answer (score 13):

A bit of [a crosspost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407977/the-italic-fonts-on-team-are-hard-to-read-in-non-capital-letters?noredirect=1#comment845676_407977) -

A recent change in the 'design' of [Cascadia Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascadia_Code) mono has rendered italic fonts to look cursive. When composing a post - the text area is in monospace. Specifically - when composing a post in the teams or "alpha" editor - using italics will result in text looking like this:

[image]

The font used for monospace italics on [Teams](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/stack-overflow-for-teams/info) (when composing a post in Markdown mode) are a little hard to read. It might be my dyslexia but, the r, f,l and s are... indistinct and significantly harder to read than the fonts used elsewhere. I'm *reasonably* certain, as someone who abuses italics for effect that this change happened *after* an update on the *OS* end - which might be an issue with using a font that seems to be in development, and I suspect an unintended, and unexpected change.

Regular Monospace looks fine:

[image]

Interestingly, the 'regular' editor doesn't have this issue since it doesn't show styles inline. It also apparently affects [italic monospace in comments](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14468/recent-win10-v20h2-update-made-comments-italicized-monospaced-content-a-cursive).

I'm on Windows 10 (build 19043) and am running [Vivaldi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vivaldi_%28web_browser%29) 3.8 (while unsupported, it's another [Blink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(browser_engine))/Chrome-based browser). I suspect, but I am unsure if the [May "Feature update to Windows 10, version 21H1"](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2021/05/18/how-to-get-the-windows-10-may-2021-update/) might have triggered this change.

Answer (score 12):

**Have you considered harmonizing fonts used for MathJax and prose?**

SE sites dedicated to natural science such as [Chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com), [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com) and [40 other sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216607) heavily rely on [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org) for written communication. There always has been a font family mismatch between the typeface used for mathematics and plain text. For example, on Chemistry.SE we deal with two fonts (**MathJax TeX** and **Georgia**) that *simply look awful used together*, not to mention Georgia is overall a poor choice of font for technical writing. We even had a brief discussion on this matter: [Should chem.SE use Georgia font?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4302/should-chem-se-use-georgia-font)

None of the aforementioned system fonts would look balanced together with MathJax at this point, and the sans fonts will be alienated from the default MathJax TeX font to the point the posts will look terrible typographically.

I realize it's a long-standing issue that cannot be immediately solved, and MathJax is a [*Ding an sich*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thing-in-itself) which doesn't help much. However, please consider the proposition of keeping both font families harmonized, or at least looking remotely similar.

One suggestion (albeit quite a bold one) would be to switch [MathJax 2.7's default font](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/output/fonts.html) to **STIX General** for the sites using MathJax, and list [**STIX**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STIX_Fonts_project) as the primary font in `ff-serif` field. STIX is an open-source serif font beloved by many scientists for its canonical appearance and wide variety of glyphs for special characters readily available.

Answer (score 10):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Ubuntu font is great for titles and fine for body text; on the whole it's a really nice improvement. BUT the code blocks are harder to read and don't look good. Ubuntu mono is too narrow.

[image: code block in Ubuntu mono, so narrow it looks like Ubuntu font]

---

A nice workaround for this was suggested to me by [Eliah Kagan](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/185080/eliah-kagan) - one can install the free-as-in-freedom Cascadia font which is higher in the stack.

I did `sudo apt install fonts-cascadia-code` on Lubuntu 20.04 - see [the repo](https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code/releases) if your distribution/version hasn't packaged it.

Cascadia is much more readable to me than Ubuntu mono and looks a lot better than the monospace fonts from the old stack as well imho.

[image: Cascadia]

Comment: Another solution is to increase the size of Ubuntu Mono on SE. I posted another answer around the same time with that suggestion and a couple of links talking about how Ubuntu Mono is known to be ~2 points smaller than many other fonts  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364275/338301

Comment: @joelostblom yeah that would be slightly better, +1

Comment: Is Cascadia not available on 18.04? [That package name doesn't exist for Bionic.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&keywords=fonts-cascadia-code)

Comment: @wjandrea Oh sorry... I think the font was only released in 2019, so that's not a big surprise.  I'm on 20.04. Should be easy enough to get it [from GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code/releases).

Comment: @Zanna I didn't want the hassle of installing the font, so I ended up installing [this userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/8932/79263) to use `monospace` instead of `ui-monospace` etc. Thanks!

Comment: Considering dropping `Ubuntu` as a font entirely in this [Stacks pull request](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/642). There isn't a clean way of getting around `Ubuntu Mono` being so small 

Comment: @AaronShekey Just wanna say I have massive respect for the patience you have shown on this entire page. I love the initiative to update the fonts. You are doing an awesome job.

Comment: Thank you, @Zanna, I really appreciate it. It's really tough balancing what I think is the right path forward for our front-end and the opinions of users who care _deeply_ about the site.

Comment: @AaronShekey Am I correct that dropping the Ubuntu font and dropping Ubuntu Mono are *separate* solutions, intended to fix separate problems? They're different fonts, after all, and personally I like the Ubuntu font as it appears on Ask Ubuntu (but I dislike Ubuntu Mono there, for the reasons Zanna described). I'm not objecting to dropping the Ubuntu font if it's causing problems for a lot of people, but dropping both fonts, *if* it's due to a problem specific to Ubuntu Mono, wouldn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Yeah the site looks wonderful in Ubuntu font to me  Users of other Linuxes seem to be getting old clunky fonts - maybe put something in the stack for them after Ubuntu font?

Answer (score 10):

The new fonts are *grim* on Mac Safari + Chrome - really terrible.

Sorry - but the system UI font is just that: for my UI. Not for reading lots of text at speed. I can genuinely feel myself reading slower with the system UI font as compared to Arial.

Yes, I realise they're both sans serif, but the UI is more difficult to read than Arial, end of. Maybe it's the small inconsistencies in Arial that means it's easier for the eye to "grasp" the text; much like ragged-right and that weird dyslexic-friendly font are both easier than pretty much any other layout or font.

Basically - the more rounded / consistent the font is, the more difficult it is to read at speed. That's why serif is consistently quicker to read.

I'm not coming here to look at pretty text. I'm coming here to quickly get answers to stuff, and the speed at which I'm able to read the text is therefore very important.

<sub>(I am unable to comment on any of these as I don't have reputation on meta.)</sub>

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The "Inbox" text at the top left of the inbox looks like a "**N**box" with a bold N on Windows/Chrome:

[image]

Comment: That's weird. It doesn't look like that for me. Perhaps it has to do with ClearType Text settings

Comment: @41686d6564 Can you throw me a screenshot?

Comment: [There](https://i.imgur.com/NQS0xGS.png).

Comment: Maybe something to do with your screen/monitor? Because I'm using chrome and windows and it's fine for me.

Answer (score 8):

Is this change fully verified if it applies to sites that use non-English languages?

Our site ([So.ja](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)) took [seven years until the design bug due to font specification was fixed.](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/99)

Comment: We were discussing this internally, and it looks like, yes, these font stacks work well in Japanese. If the community disagrees and we need to bail, we can always specify the existing Arial on a per-community basis. In theory, moving to system fonts should give us _more_ international characters, not less.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think the update caused the blue badges on the profile page tabs not to be centered vertically anymore:

[image]

(Firefox, macOS)

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297044/295232) is an example how it looked like:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Author highlight of comments overlaps with above text

[image: Character 'g' is underneath the below highlight]

As you can see, the bottom part of the letter 'g' is hiding underneath the author highlight of the comment.

I think the best way to fix this is to make sure that the line with the name is spaced further from the text above.

Comment: Duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364262/295232

Answer (score 7):

## The navigation bar doesn't look so good

[image: Screen shot]

- The padding above and below the search field are not the same any more.
- The <kbd>+10</kbd> looks too far south-west.

Comment: *All* boxes look misaligned. That includes the tags beneath a question, the `<kbd>` box in your answer, and the `[Active]`, `[Oldest]`, `[Votes]` selection, for example.

Answer (score 7):

While I can't exactly provide a screenshot of it "faded" out elements - like "seen" but unhandled flags in the mod flag queue are indistinct and rather hard to read.

Answer (score 7):

I am not an expert in fonts, their names and everything.

But I am *very* upset to see Stack Overflow fonts were changed and everything looks *very* ugly to me now (Windows, Chrome).

Below are screenshots. The posts are simply much *harder* to read now.

### Can you please return fonts back?

Again, I am not an expert, so I don't know what to do to have them like they were just a week ago. Just do it to me in the simplest possible way, thanks!

### In the future: please!

Do not apply your awesome changes before I see them and tell you what I am thinking. You never seems to learn this very simple rule.

P.S.: the post may sounds arrogant, but I am  intentionally using "I" instead of "we", "users" of "community".

---

### [image]

### [image]

Comment: What exactly are the things that are problematic? And well, your OS would be a useful data point since different OSes are rendering different fonts

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, saying third time, I am not an expert. It's *ugly*. It hurts my eyes. It was working before for years and now out of sudden the change. There are *more* important things to do. I am at boiling point now, it is harder to use site now. I wrote "Windows" and perhaps you can identify font from screenshot?

Comment: Revisiting my post after some time. I must admit the new fonts looks Ok to me now. I just needed few weeks to get used to them. I still prefer [the older](https://web.archive.org/web/20191001141736/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/how-to-enumerate-an-enum) fonts for long code block though. The new font is simply a wrong choice.

Comment: The windows one? I have a [definite issue with that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364881/135565) :D

Answer (score 6):

The font weight of Cascadia Mono is rather heavy, compared to the regular text font Segoe UI. Consolas looks much more comparable. However, another reason is that (on my machine at least) it's impossible to uninstall the Cascadia fonts as they are a part of the Windows Terminal app (ie, the only way to get rid of them is to uninstall the app). It's possible to uninstall Consolas if you don't like it.

Comment: Windows 10 user on Firefox. 100% my feelings. I don't like `Cascadia Mono`, it's too bold. The code looks much bolder than non-code. and the font is impossible to uninstall. `Consolas` looks much better.

Comment: Screenshot of Cascadia rendering: https://i.imgur.com/OWIjBOP.png

It looks especially jarring when code is not syntax highlighted (for example in <textarea> when editing): https://i.imgur.com/EJIMfB5.png

Comment: Windows 10 has fonts that cannot be uninstalled without also installing other software?  When you go to the `Fonts` folder, what does it say when you try to delete it?  Or is it not even listed?

Comment: I think Cascadia is too heavy as used at the moment, but I don't want to uninstall it either.

Answer (score 5):

On Android Firefox it seems like it will permit more text on screen, compare [before, after, and overlaid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFR0N.jpg); though it will also change the number of characters on a line, and reopen (or aggravate) the bug reports about [long names / tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306372/282094), and overflowing [columnar text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all).

Comment: Where are you getting your after screenshot from? We haven't shipped these changes yet. Regardless, the font shouldn't change at all on Android, since we're already rendering it today in Roboto since Android doesn't have Arial.  I've verified using the Stacks documentation site that the current production text matches the proposed font stack exactly. You can compare [production](https://stackoverflow.design) to [staging](https://deploy-preview-282--stacks.netlify.app).

Comment: @AaronShekey, [Comparing production and staging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzizp.png) shows those fonts are identical; the only difference in the superimposed images is the browser's URL field. --- My example was produced by using my phone's UI to access the Accessibility Settings and force the font change to be applied; that's no different from a different browser where you would change the fonts, nor the result that would be expected, and the applicability of those other reports.

Comment: A perhaps simpler explanation is that fonts have different names because they are different, excluding someone who has *created* a font by copying and renaming. While the [anatomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface_anatomy) may be consistent the vertical and horizontal [proportion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface#Proportion) usually differs when rendered at the same size; and decimal sizes still don't align exactly depending on the character composition of each line.

Comment: Here's a very small sampling of some of the complaints, which are supportive of my answer here, that resulted when we changed the fonts: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316797/282094  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353525/282094  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316196/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311033/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317237/282094

Answer (score 5):

Segoe UI vs Arial... Windows are of same size. The first seems more compact (Chrome, Windows)

[image]

Comment: This explains why all of a sudden i have to start zooming in on StackOverflow. 

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if it's a good *or* bad thing, but I wanted to acknowledge it anyway– On Mac now, with the new font selection, diamonds next to site mod usernames are *huge* in comparison to how they looked beforehand:

[image: Diamonds are big in mod usernames]

This is without a doubt just a quirk of using a new font, but wanted to report it in case it's undesirable.

Comment: Same for Firefox on Windows, but to a lesser extent.

Comment: Maybe it's implying the moderators deserve more "recognition" 

Comment: Reminds me of [a similar issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176715/241919) that happened a long time ago...

Comment: Perhaps it's time to switch that diamond to an image?

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

On mobile web, revision summaries are now displayed in a bold font, putting focus on something that's not really important:

[image: new look with bold font on "asked 3hours ago" text]

Former:

[image: former look, normal font]

Chrome 85.0 for Android 5.1.1.

Comment: If this is unrelated to the font changes, I can post this as a separate bug report (or feature request, if that's intended behaviour).

Answer (score 5):

I have a custom-tailored Chrome extension to bring back the old fonts:

---

#### **[CHROME EXTENSION](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/revert-stackexchange-form/fliedkodjpgomjmjbkaehhlllnhmcjnh)**

---

- Reverts text fonts to **Arial** and code fonts to **Consolas**
- other customizable settings...

  > *turn off all other options if you only need to revert the fonts*

This was originally developed to revert the [formatting changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353525/please-revert-the-line-height-change) (specifically the line height change) introduced in August 2020, but has since been extended to support other revertable changes as well.

[image]

I added the option to revert fonts back in May, but didn't get around to posting this till now. Hopefully people are still searching for easy solutions to the new fonts.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to consider a font from the [candidates for new default fonts for Windows](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3616707/microsoft-is-choosing-a-new-default-font-for-windows-office-and-more.html) expected in 2022. And if you consider that, you may want to wait until Microsoft makes their final choice, or stick with Segoe UI until then, and then switch. Just a thought.

I do recognize all Windows users aren't Windows 10 users. Perhaps Segoe UI for Windows <10 and one of the new ones for Windows 10.

Comment: The article isn't talking about replacing Segoe UI, the font in user interfaces, but Calibri, the font used in Office. Don't see a need to change here.

Comment: I'm not following. I don't see Calibri mentioned anywhere. My thoughts are if you are going for a Windows system font for browsers on WIndows, at some point, they may want to look at those (around 2022).

Comment: To quote from the article (emphasis added): *Microsoft has commissioned five new fonts as potential replacements **for Calibri**.*

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog hmm that article says "Microsoft has commissioned five new fonts, one of which will replace Calibri as the default font to be used in **Windows**, Office **and more**" and "Calibri went on to be Microsoft's default font everywhere", indicating it's not just for office.

Comment: Also, what about users who choose to run older builds of Windows 10, such as the LTSC branch or simply an older release build? I'm still running 1909 on my laptop (and have the Education edition so it's still supported).

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Sorry - I misread the word "article" as meaning the OP here at meta.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Arn't system fonts set... system wide? So if windows 10 v21Hx sets the new font as a default, everything will switch with it. And while unsupported, other OSes may have their own font choices, not that explicit haiku support is a given

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Some headers and paragraphs in the [Code of Conduct](/conduct) are still in Roboto:

[image]

The bottom paragraph is in the system font, as expected.

Comment: This is actually a typeface we use in [branded pages](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) like the code of conduct. We could argue the CoC doesn't need the branded font, but for now, this is `status-bydesign`

Comment: @KonradRudolph Doesn't appear to be monospace

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It seems to not be in effect for https://stackexchange.com . Will it be, or is this only for specific sites?

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Looking into this one!

Comment: This will go live in the next build, whenever that is.

Comment: @AaronShekey It is more than 18 hours from the status change, but still the font change is not effected in https://stackexchange.com

Comment: I shipped the changes there, but I'll check on the deployment.

Comment: @AaronShekey Now I can see the changes in the stackexchange.com, but the [header and site switcher still using the Arial font](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364340/312043)

Answer (score 4):

Fonts are one of those things that... I struggle to care about. So many other people care about them A LOT, just feels like there's enough care to go around without me.

But I do care about code readability, and *damn...* On Windows 10, this is a HUGE improvement in readability for code blocks.

Don't get me wrong, Consolas was pretty nice... A decade ago. Shucks, I remember tuning my LCD monitor to get that sweet subpixel antialiasing dialed in *juuuuust right*. But... That was a long time ago. Screen resolution has gotten better. And so have fonts. This Cascadia deal is a nice step up!

Comment: I don't agree with Cascadia point. It's much bolder than Consolas and all non-code fonts on the page. It feels like from entirely different universe, it just doesn't fit. Especially when code is not syntax highlighted (for example in <textarea> when editing)

Comment: See, I don't mind the weight. For a good chunk of SO's life, the fonts used were heavier *across the board* - *several* past redesigns had the net effect of lightening them. That... Might actually be nice in terms of eye strain for long bits of prose; it annoyed me at the time, but I've gotten used to it. That said, I don't see the value for code; if I'm looking for an issue in someone's snippet, the LAST thing I want to do is quickly skim past it!

Answer (score 4):

**Chrome** on **Mac** seems wider now than the previous typography. The most noticeable change I am experiencing is the longer time it takes to read the text.
[image]

I will give it some time if that would still be the case later on.

Comment: Agreed - the rounded font is far slower to read. Easy on the eye, maybe - but it's for UIs, not walls of text.

Comment: **Update**: After 3 days of observation, I still have the same comment. It still takes longer time to read the text.

Answer (score 4):

Would you consider removing `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` to make the text more readable?

Comment: https://usabilitypost.com/2012/11/05/stop-fixing-font-smoothing/

Answer (score 4):

## Fonts are too light on Safari 14.1 on macOS

So lots of chatter here, but will say this as a macOS Big Sur (11.3.1) user, the font weight is overall way too light in Safari.

A simple comparison between how SuperUser renders in Safari 14.1 versus Firefox 88.0.1 shows the difference clearly on my side. Right side of this screenshot is Firefox and the left side is Safari.

I don’t have these issues on any other websites; only Stack Exchange sites since the change was made.

> [image]

---

#### UPDATE 2021-05-17

So was this tweaked or fixed? Or am I losing my mind? Looking at the site today (Monday, May 17th) it seems like all is even and the same on Safari and Firefox:

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

I didn't find any information on whether these changes are applied with A/B testing to validate them or not. Are they?

(Please, don't tell me there is no A/B testing involved, and this random change went live without any knowledge of the change to website quality whatsover. What if the readability went down 50% for several million users, and just by total extra time spent reading answers you killed a small family, and keep killing another small family every day this change is still in production? I'd hate to be *this* person.)

Comment: Yeah, this is an A/B test. We are all in the B group; you can log out any time you like, but you can never leave. Some browse to remember, some browse to forget.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox)

The bottom part of 'g' is partially visible in the [home page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) of **Mozilla Firefox** browser, when the post contains one of the watched tag ("featured" is my watched tag) and the modified content is displayed in the next line.

There is another post with "featured" tag, but the modified content is displayed in the same line, but there is no partial display issue.

Screenshots for reference:

[image: Firefox]

[image]

| Configuration | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Operating System | Windows 10 |
| Browser | Mozilla Firefox 88.0.1 (64-bit) |
| Zoom | 100% |

Comment: LOL, another buq aqain `:)`

Answer (score 3):

Not that I care deeply, but your post said that Christianity.SE wasn't changing typefaces, but we just did!

The "Top Questions" header switched to sans, thinking a font at that size wouldn't be a problem for screen readers. I think the comments changed on meta. Something feels different there.  Blurb on the right side looks better imo.

If that's the way it's going to be, I've got no gripes with it. I thought it was interesting or unexpected that the was a change.  But I guess the if the blurb had been "sites that have custom typefaces will now have a mishmash of sans and serif fonts" I would have been apt to voice my displeasure.

The only thing I really don't like is "Top Questions" being sans right underneath the very serif'ed logo.

Our site now looks like one of those half-hearted Stack Exchange beta sites from 10 years ago.

Comment: While I see some of the site in system fonts (such as user profiles), the main Q&A content is still in your font, as far as I can tell. Can you be more specific about what you're coming across?

Comment: @Catija I noted some things

Comment: The "Top Questions" thing (as far as I'm aware) has always been sans, even on sites with serif stacks. I remember thinking it was odd at the outset. Now, that doesn't necessarily mean it was the case for y'all, too... just I remember it being mentioned as something odd when we did this a couple years ago.

Comment: @catija ok chalk it up to the Mandela Effect then.  I think many folks would prefer to be serif-free (or at the very least 100% consistent), but have some sort of one-box for special quotes (i.e. Biblical quotes), we've had that request for quite a while I thought it was getting into a serious review last year, but hadn't heard anything lately.

Comment: Yeah, you're not the only site that'd like a special quote style for particular things - I think most of the religion sites would like that, too. :) I'm not enough of an expert in CommonMark to know whether it's possible to have two different quote formats like that, unfortunately.

Comment: Any idea you guys [declined this](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20/add-markdown-and-or-onebox-support-for-biblegateway) btw?  I missed that back in February.

Comment: I can double check on that - in general, we're really short on time to support features that only impact a single site (or very small number of sites), so that's likely why it was declined instead of deferred. We have a really small dev team and I'm not sure how much work would have to be done to allow that feature. I absolutely see the value in time savings for y'all, I just don't think we have the bandwidth to build it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [stackexchange.com](/questions/tagged/stackexchange.com)

---

The https://stackexchange.com site's header and site switcher still contains the Arial font only, but the remaining part of the page contains the Segoe UI font on Windows OS.

Screenshots for reference:

**stackexchange.com header:**

[image: SE Header]

**stackexchange.com site switcher:**

[image: SE site switcher]

Comment: This is a design nightmare. The benefits clearly don't outweigh the negatives. You can't just go wading into a very mature design of an even more mature SaaS app and think you can reset a few main fonts and not have the design suffer. Obviously not thought all the way through.

Comment: @AaronShekey Seems the issue has been fixed, please validate and change the tag to status-completed

Answer (score 3):

Why not using a font specifically built for readbility, such as Lexend for all platforms?  https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lexend

[image: Sample of Lexend]

Comment: Presumably because requiring that a browser install a new font to properly render the page makes the page slower to load.

Comment: @Catija Either that, or it displays some placeholder font for a few seconds while the actual font loads. I regularly use a website that does that and it ain't pretty.

Comment: @F1Krazy But that would happen only once and then hopefully the browser is caching the font, wouldn't it?

Comment: This would happen once. People visit SO thousands of times a day. Cache works.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

I believe this change may have broken responsiveness on English Language & Usage when someone edits a post.

I'm not entirely sure, because I don't edit on EL&U as often as I do on ELL, but I have edited posts on EL&U on my phone before and I don't remember it being such a chore. The site is responsive when I'm just reading, so it's I didn't accidentally switch responsiveness off (the bottom of the page still has links to switch to "Mobile" and to "Disable responsiveness").

This happens on my iPhone in both Safari and the DuckDuckGo browser. It happens on my Mac in both Firefox and Safari. Also in Firefox on Windows. I don't remember it happening prior to the font change (I had edited several posts on EL&U on May 7th).

Editing an answer on EL&U, which I believe has a customized design:

> [image: Screenshot of editing an answer on EL&U, which displays poorly in a narrow window]

Editing an answer on ELL, which is using the same sans-serif font as the rest of the network:

> [image: Screenshot of editing an answer on ELL, which displays correctly in a narrow window]

Answer (score 2):

> If consistency were the absolute goal, we’d ship our own custom font. I would love to be able to truly express our brand through a typeface, but that means users would have to download custom fonts and wait for them to display. We’d also have to cover international character sets. Displaying custom fonts is getting more realistic every day at our scale, so we may revisit that choice at some point, and come back to a more consistent experience. System fonts let us modernize in the meantime without too many drawbacks.

Not quite about the current situation but - how *bad* does using custom fonts look in terms of performance and what's the future changes that make it more realistic?

Comment: I think of our front end as a budget. Right now, much of our CSS could be deleted and replaced by the fixed-size Stacks library. Much of our JS could be consolidated with far less duplication. It will require sustained effort and we’re staffing a front-end team with Stacks at the center. I hope someday we can budget for a single effective, legible, variable weight typeface that doesn’t trash performance. I think the web will evolve while we pay down technical debt. The biggest hurdle is most the tricks to make web fonts performant tend to break down at our scale.

Comment: @AaronShekey, *"we can budget for a single effective, legible, variable weight typeface"* - you forgot the most important feature of font - it has to be *readable*.

Comment: Legible means readable fwiw.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek and this one isn't, at certain resolutions.

Comment: Well yes, but I'm asking about the future - since being able to use a webfont means a consistent look across OSes. Right now? Yeah, there's a lot covering that.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [stackexchange.com](/questions/tagged/stackexchange.com)

The font in the dropdown list of [StackExchange.com - Top Users](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow) still contains the "Tahoma" font. All other places in the page contains the "Segoe UI" font.

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do we have to force refresh/flush cache Stack Overflow  websites for it to re-cache the new fonts or not?

Comment: Our cache on the CSS side isn't too aggressive, so I don't think you'll need to do anything fancy to see the changes when they're live.

Comment: Ok, this is good to know then.

Answer (score 1):

I got a notification e-mail about a comment, viewed in Thunderbird on Ubuntu:

[image]

This looks different from the same notification on the website, viewed in Firefox on Ubuntu:

[image]

Thunderbird uses Gecko to render (same as Firefox). Are there any plans to make the fonts consistent?

Comment: Now that I think about it the e-mail was sent yesterday night already, it should have been after the change (e-mail time is 19:05Z) but possibly the e-mail handler was still being updated. If the next notification I get is in the Ubuntu font in Thunderbird then I'll delete this answer.

Comment: I got another notification today with the old font where both the new comment and the e-mail were definitely posted/sent after the font change, so this inconsistency is actually present.

Answer (score 1):

Linux user here.  I'm happy enough with the Ubuntu font family that I haven't had any real issues with its appearance on any of my machines.

I'd rather not use or leverage Arial since the fallbacks can be *horrible* depending on how my system renders them (Pop!_OS).

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to pop in, and unlike all the endless people complaining about the changes, wanted to mention I looked around for this post to figure out why everything looks so much better now. I especially love the use of Cascadia Mono for code on Windows, it's fantastic!

Sorry, would have posted this as a comment, but I can't due to lack of reputation since I don't ever post otherwise.

Comment: How much SE paid you to post this answer? ;-)

Comment: I appreciate it, @CaiB. Our intent is always to improve things for our users, and if we can look to the future while doing it, that's a bonus. Welcome to MSE 

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard Both your checks are in the mail 

Comment: Interesting how quickly this one got a response, compared to people who are having issues with the new fonts. 

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard Sadly nothing yet >_< - However the message was in earnest. I love Cascadia Mono for code, and switched all my editors to use it a while back. Seeing it on SE was a pleasant surprise!

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard LOL!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure if it hasn't come up anywhere else, but to me the bold rendered text elements are too strong. They are kind of jumping into my face and trying to constantly draw attention to them. I would prefer them with a lower weight/strength. Not sure if this has changed though or if I just now realize it. Is there a way that I could fix this for me (Windows 10)? If so how?

[image]

Comment: It seems super bold compared to the much skinnier text, and that looks leaner than on windows for me. Saying what OS might be useful

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Added OS info. I'm also worried a bit about consistency, but mostly I wonder if it always was like this?

Comment: Oh, from what's being talked about, there's going to be inconsistancy - since they're going for OS defaults. Hence the need to mention the OS

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAE7B.png that's what it looks like for me

Comment: Wait, I'm also on windows 10... why does it look different?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I have no idea. Is there maybe more information that I should provide?

Comment: Now I'm slightly more confused than you are