# Descenders are clipped with new fonts

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, fonts

With the [new font change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364048/401803) today, descenders are clipped in edit boxes in Chrome, Windows 10.

The letters I've typed into the *search* and *title* boxes are are `g` and `q` (in that order), which look nearly identical due to the clipped descender of the g.  The letters `j` and `y` are negatively affected too.

[image: Screenshot of clipped descenders on Stack Exchange Meta]

Here's a side-by-side comparison of the problem with the characters `g-j-q-y`.

[image: Comparison of clipped and unclipped descenders]

I took these screenshots 2021-05-10 in Chrome on Windows 10.

Comment: Related to [We are switching to system fonts on May 10, 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021)

Comment: Stackoverflow supports only characters from their official "The Key" keyboard https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/03/31/the-key-copy-paste - use all other characters at your own risk :)

Comment: Well, [no repro on Chrome v90.0.4430.93 on Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bnc7p.png) at least, can't speak for Windows atm.

Comment: [No repro on Firefox 90.0a1 on Win 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkXY8.png)

Comment: this new redesign is so much easier to read IMO, other than these notble problems

Comment: I was just reporting [another issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364348/vertical-aligment-issues-with-new-system-fonts-particularly-in-tags) related with the new fonts, and when I wrote a "g" in the title I were hit by this other one! :-)

Comment: **To close voters**: the issue was *fixed*, not *no longer reproducible*. That close reason is intended for *ephemeral* issues that resolve themselves after a short while, not for actual bugs that are later fixed by the team. The [tag:status-completed] tag is enough.

Comment: Just marking this as status-completed since it has since been fixed.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be fixed as of 2021-05-17.

It seems likely that Stack Exchange has made an adjustment to the CSS to avoid the clipping. (Would be nice to have confirmation of this.)

Here I present side-by-side screenshots (magnified 4x) showing the descenders have been restored (are no longer clipped).  If you look at the interface between the two screenshots (I purposely did not include a separator) then you can also see that the search box has been made larger vertically by 1 pixel at the top and 1 pixel at the bottom.

[image: side-by-side comparison of clipping fix]

Thanks, Stack Exchange!