# Vertical aligment issues with new "system" fonts, particularly in tags

Tags: bug, design, fonts

I'm noticing (small but annoying) issues in the vertical aligment of texts inside tag boxes, since the switch to the [new system fonts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021). I'm using Chrome 90.0.4430.212 with Windows 10.

[image]

In this example, the tags "elementary-number-theory" and "decimal-expansion" seem to lay closer to the bottom than the "partial-differential-equations". And indeed they are, by one pixel. The CSS seems to be all right, the problem seems to be in the font itself.

[image]

Comment: Possibly a duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364286/descenders-are-clipped-with-new-fonts - the descenders are ignored in calculations and resulting rendering; sometimes clipping, here spoiling the vertical centering. I can't explain the inconsistent results.