# Letter descenders cut off using full site on Safari

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, fonts

Some of the descenders on words on the home page are cut off.

For example the ‘g’s in the picture below.

I’m using the full site on Safari running on iOS 14.6.

[image: this picture]

Comment: Possibly related: [Descenders are clipped with new fonts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364286/369802) but also [Profile images are pushed to next line if tags extend too far to the right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366329/369802)? I don't see this on my laptop + chrome but can reproduce this using full site on my phone (android + chrome) with a question on the /active page, but only where the tags push the username down like it happens in your screenshot too: https://i.stack.imgur.com/id63A.jpg

Comment: I think those "letters" could be referred to as [glyphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph).

Comment: It's the [same buq](/q/364286/350567) aqain `:)`

Comment: This was happening for me until recently, and now it isn't.

Comment: @iBugsaysReinstateMonica notice the two "g" s.

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been fixed (the positioning of "modified { } hour(s) ago" and "asked { } hour(s) ago" has also been changed since then):

> [image: Image showing that descenders on words are no longer cut off on the Home page]

(Tested on Chrome for Android.)

Comment: I'd say "fixed by chance", as they changed other things, fixing some bug indirectly.