# The Stack Overflow front page is hard to read now (too little contrast)

Tags: bug, homepage, fonts

For some reason, the front page of Stack Overflow is difficult to read now. There is much less contrast between the text and the white background, which requires that I really concentrate to read the text. I'm using the latest Chrome on macOS.

Here is a screenshot. Note that the PNG screenshot shows a little bit more contrast than what I see on my screen. I've been visiting Stack Overflow for 10+ years, so I know what's in front of my eyes.

[image]

Comment: I think you're supposed to post this as an answer on this question https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048

Comment: (also, screenshots are always helpful)

Comment: Could it be that your screen is low DPI or low brightness? There is enough contrast showing for me.

Comment: @10Rep: No, the front page is clearly different than how it was a week ago.

Comment: Close, but what you're actually seeing is a different font than what used to be there.

Comment: Yeah, it's the font that changed. Nothing to do with text color or contrast.

Comment: Ok then, how do I disable the font change?

Comment: Have you tried the methods suggested by Luuklag in their answer?

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned by others the only thing that recently changed was the font. It was announced in this post: [We are switching to system fonts on May 10, 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021?cb=1)
This was featured so would have been visible to you in the Stack Overflow sidebar, if you have that enabled.

Perhaps you could increase the contrast by using Stack Overflows dark mode, you can enable that in your [user preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/me).

Another alternative would be to run a userscript to change the font to a font of your liking, there have been several of these script posted as answers to the question linked above. See for example [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364269/361484) using stylus, or [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364285/361484) using a dedicated userscript.

Comment: What's a `userscript`?

Comment: A program you can run in your browser.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 [Wikipedia](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript).