# Where would I start with creating a custom stylesheet for SE?

Tags: support, design

I'm currently using this *excellent* solution from the thread [on the new themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021/364271#364271) with some changes, alternating with the new theme - they both have advantages and disadvantages

I've got specific needs that probably will *never* match up with SE's UX guidelines - essentially preferring a bigger font size (which the stylesheet above doesn't provide), more width (to go with the bigger font size) and so on. I'd prefer a stylesheet over an extension since I can 'easily' tweak it as I go along, and I might do changes based on the machine, following specific preferences.

Unfortunately I'm in that weird place where I'm confident enough to mess with things like this, but not having any knowledge of web (or any) dev) - I don't know where to look, and what to start tweaking and how.

This *isn't* a "I hate it all" request - I'm looking at how to adjust my 'experience' of SE for very personalised needs

- Bigger fonts, and specific ones I find more readable
- I've a bigger screen, and the large fonts and adjustable line width help me pick a number of columns that work well on that font size. Zooming on SE kinda...squishes everything into the middle column.
- It won't break the whole world - and it might be useful for people with worse dyslexia than me to use comic sans, while I go would source sans and source code pro...

Comment: I can understand why you posted this here on MSE, but I personally feel that it is off-topic here. As this is more of a software design question. Stack-apps, of SO might be a better question, albeit it being awful broad for the latter.

Comment: @Luuklag I don't think this is off-topic at all. This is basically a support question that doesn't belong on a specific meta, thus it goes here.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen, the place for this would be SO but there are lots of posts about customizing UX on SE (especially as opportune answers whenever there's a system change). I'm also having readability problems so I'd like to see what might come of this thread.

Comment: @bad_coder No, in its current form this is definitely not an SO question, as it's too broad/unclear: effectively this is asking for a tutorial on how to reverse engineer a website in order to make unclear, under-specified changes to it. Even if it was asking for specific changes, its current form relies on information which isn't in the question proper. What needs to be altered by the script *will* change at some point in the future when SO updates their HTML/CSS (as almost anyone who's written code for such changes could attest about what a pain it is to keep them updated).

Comment: @Makyen Points taken, deciding if this thread should be left open or closed takes real subject matter expertise.

Comment: Hence the  desire to have a single place to have that sorta thing documented - Its not an SO question, but there's no 'clean' way to have a resource for people to get information to do it themselves. And MSE feels like a 'natural' place for it. Stackapps was suggested but I feel its for completed scripts. Unless someone decided to create a github repo, but we'd still need to point to it.

Comment: I've read the points made here, but overall I think this is on-topic enough.  Voted to reopen