# Is there any way we can experiment with site design locally, or in some kind of sandbox?

Tags: discussion, design, sandbox

There's been [movement at the station](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378888/351283) with regards to site design for beta sites, and Stack Exchange staff are asking for feedback in meta posts, like [this one](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4448/24699) at Spanish.SE.  I'm just wondering if there is any way us users can play around with designs, so as to facilitate more concrete discussions.

**Question**: Is there any way we can experiment with site design locally, or in some kind of sandbox?

I can whip up mock-ups in drawing packages, but I feel like it should be possible for some script to implement it locally:

> [image]

Comment: Somewhat related: [Where would I start with creating a custom stylesheet for SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364541/where-would-i-start-with-creating-a-custom-stylesheet-for-se) - though I was thinking of resources and documentation for themes, over actual themeage

Answer (score 1):

The usual way for me to experiment with styling on *all* websites is to use my browser's developer tools, e.g. as described in [Click and edit CSS with Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2857835/4751173). The downside is that refreshing the page or navigating away undoes your changes.

I guess a better solution for long-term experimenting would be to

- download the site's specific styling, which is coming from an URL like https://meta.stackexchange.com/Content/Sites/stackexchangemeta/primary.css
- block that URL with an ad blocker
- insert your own copy with a browser plugin like [Stylus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne?hl=en)

but I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: Probably could be achieved a lot easier here, depending on what level of customization you wanted to do. For example, the colors are based on only a handful of CSS variables that could be overwritten in a custom stylesheet. E.g. `--theme-base-primary-color-h`, `--theme-base-primary-color-s`, and `--theme-base-primary-color-l` on the body control the primary color of the page directly. (This simplicity was the purpose of the design overhaul that delayed custom themes for so long.)