# Code blocks and markup font looks bolder because of Cascadia Mono - is this intentional?

Tags: support, fonts

I'm not sure if it's related to the [system font change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021):

On the last few days, the font in code blocks and markups (as in the window where I'm writing this question) became bolder on my home PC (left screenshot), but not on my work PC (right).

They're both Windows 10, both Chrome, but this reproduces regardless of the browser. This is also demonstrated in the Web Archive versions ([19.3.2021](https://web.archive.org/web/20210319190716/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/string-concatenation-concat-vs-operator) vs. [23.6.2021](https://web.archive.org/web/20210623104242/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/string-concatenation-concat-vs-operator)) of the same page I screenshot, which suggests that it's related to the system-font change, though I'm not sure why it's only manifested on the last few days.

I played with the css and removed `"Cascadia Mono"` font-family on my home PC, which got me the previous, thiner `consolas` look.

**My question:** Is the bolder look intentional?

[image]

**EDIT**: I realized that `Cascadia Mono` was installed on my home PC when I installed Windows Terminal. Anyway, my question still remains - personally, I prefer the `consolas` look.

I hope SE can just change the current css from:

```
--ff-mono: ui-monospace,"Cascadia Mono","Segoe UI Mono","Liberation Mono",Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,monospace;
```

to:

```
--ff-mono: Consolas,ui-monospace,"Cascadia Mono","Segoe UI Mono","Liberation Mono",Menlo,Monaco,monospace;
```

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: @SantoshGupta7, the only way I know of to "resolve" this is to remove the "Cascadia Mono" font-family from your pc.