# How can I change the fonts of the code snippets in Stack Overflow back to Consolas?

Tags: support, code-formatting, fonts

I've installed the [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) from Microsoft Store and, together with it, the [Cascadia Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascadia_Code) font family (mono and code) in my system, but I don't use them.

Since then, the [snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/stack-snippets/info) on Stack Overflow had its fonts changed from [Consolas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolas) to Cascadia Mono.

I could uninstall Cascadia Mono from my system, but I can't do that without uninstalling Windows Terminal.

What is the way to get back Consolas in the code snippets of Stack Overflow?

Comment: Duplicate (with no answers yet): [Code blocks and markup font looks bolder because of Cascadia Mono - is this intentional?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368632/348196)

Comment: I encountered the new font after upgrading to Win11 yesterday, there is a userscript [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/8932/custom-fonts-user-script-revert-or-improve-the-font-updates) which improves it (as well as changing a few other fonts).

Comment: @41686d6564 the other one asks only why it's like that, the one here asks to change it. So not obvious duplicates.

Comment: You can install a user style containing the relevant parts of https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364271.

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: @SantoshGupta7, not so far . . .