# The code used in code blocks for Stack Overflow has changed after I installed some new fonts on my system. How can I change it back?

Tags: support, design, code-formatting, fonts

I was installing and testing new fonts in my macOS for use in [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code). After I was finished with that, I noticed the font has changed in Stack Overflow code blocks to one I do not prefer.

As far as I can tell from *[We are switching to system fonts on May 10, 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021) installing*, new fonts should not have changed what is on Stack Overflow. I am using macOS, so it would have been [San Francisco Mono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Francisco_(sans-serif_typeface)#SF_Mono) (SF Mono) before and after I installed the new fonts, but it is not that.

Here is a picture of what I see

[image: 1]

The zero is dotted, but in SF Mono the zeros are slashed.

I have AverageMono installed as my Chrome monospace font, which is not the Stack Overflow code font either, since its zeros are not dotted nor slashed in AverageMono.

I looked at Stack Overflow on other browsers and it's showing the same font, so it does not seem to be a browser-specific issue.

Comment: If it is possible, could you check the rendered/computed `font-family` from the Developer Tools? On Windows+Chrome, it's listing: `ui-monospace, "Cascadia Mono", "Segoe UI Mono", "Liberation Mono", Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, monospace`, which according to [this article](https://qwtel.com/posts/software/the-monospaced-system-ui-css-font-stack/), it should be prioritizing "SF Mono" already.

Comment: I have MacOS but I right clicked -> inspect element and in the styles tab, I typed "ui-monospace" in the filters box. I found `--ff-mono: ui-monospace,"Cascadia Mono","Segoe UI Mono","Liberation Mono",Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,monospace;`. Is this what was needed, or something else?