# Unicode combining character not combining correctly across multiple browsers on macOS

Tags: support, bug, unicode, fonts, mac

The Russian language sometimes uses stress marks above its vowels.  These stress marks should appear over the centre of a letter they are marking.

When I type a Russian character with a stress mark, for example `а́`,  i.e.:

- `а` (U+0430 : CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER A), followed by
- `́` (U+0301 : COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT)

... it looks fine in the editor, but something is going wrong in the render.  The stress mark appears *next to the letter* rather than over it;  it isn't combining correctly:

[image: Stress marks above letter in editor, but next to letter in render]

This is also apparent when I'm trying to read other posts, e.g. [this answer](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/14190/18988) looks like:

[image: Post with stress marks shown next to Russian vowels]

---

The bug happens when I'm using the latest versions of the supported web browsers: *Chrome 114*, *Edge 114*, *Firefox 113*, or *Opera 99*; but strangely not with *Safari 16.5*
I am using the operating system: *macOS Ventura 13.4*

**Has anyone else encountered this bug?**
**How can I fix it?**

I'm not sure if there is a problem with my computer, the browsers, the fonts, Stack Exchange, or something else.  So I'm not really sure if I should post this here  <s>([Russian Language Meta](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com)),</s> [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com), another SE site, or elsewhere.

#### For Reference

Russian uses the following Cyrillic letters combined with stress marks:

```plaintext
А́ а́ Е́ е́ И́ и́ О́ о́ У́ у́ Ы́ ы́ Э́ э́ Ю́ ю́ Я́ я́
```

#### Firefox Workaround

In *Firefox*, the fonts – advanced settings, allows preferences for various writing systems. Selecting "Cyrillic" and then unchecking the option to "Allow pages to choose their own fonts, [...]" fixes the issue, for *Firefox*.
But this setting does not exist in *Google Chrome*, *Edge*, or *Opera*.

---

To avoid this bug, the [Russian Language](https://russian.stackexchange.com) site (and other language specific sites) really ought to use a font that can display both letters and symbols that are particular to that language, regardless of the user's setup (operating system / browser).

#### Related

- [Better font for rendering IPA (esp. diacritics)](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/600/better-font-for-rendering-ipa-esp-diacritics)

Comment: I'm not seeing anything like that on any of the Chromium-based browsers on Windows, Linux or Android: https://i.imgur.com/Z9XzXxb.png. I don't have any Apple's devices though.

Comment: I'm not seeing it on Mac Safari right back to Safari 14 [Mojave]. Could you add a line of the affected characters as text to the question, to make it easier for others [non-Russian speakers] to test. I can find these chars in the Char Viewer, but I have to find them by unicode number & double click to enter them… a bit of a faff ;)

Comment: @Quassnoi [unable to reproduce on iPad (Chrome) as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b6IV.jpg)

Comment: It is frankly not very likely that Stack Exchange can fix this problem. Looking at the characters in the HTML source, they appear to be standard Cyrillic Unicode characters followed by U+0301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT - which is exactly how you're supposed to put an acute accent over an arbitrary character. It is the responsibility of the browser to figure out how to render that correctly.

Comment: This is likely a font problem.

Comment: Just a reminder that [SE is now using system fonts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364048/241919), so different OS may use different fonts, though browsers may also overwrite the font choices.

Comment: Thank you for adding these as text. I can confirm it's already broken in older versions of Chrome [106.0.5249.91] & Firefox [108.0.1 ] but not Safari [14.1.2] all running on Mojave 10.14. They're also fine copy/pasted into any regular text document on the Mac, so this is likely a fault [one of many] in Chrome & Firefox - well-known for ignoring Mac Toolbox guidelines. You're left with reporting to each of them just what happens when these things are ignored ;))

Comment: @Kevin Stack Exchange could fix this problem by 
using a font on its Russian Language site(s) 
such that its "supported" browsers / operating systems 
can render Russian characters.

Comment: Have you opened web developer tools to see which font is being picked?

Comment: @user3840170 I've used a browser extension called *WhatFont* that says the font is `"system-ui"` — whatever that means.